# How can I select the last element with a specific class, not last child inside of parent?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="commentList">
   <article class="comment " id="com21"></article>
   <article class="comment " id="com20"></article>
   <article class="comment " id="com19"></article>
   <div class="something"> hello </div>
</div>
```

I want to select `#com19` ?

```
.comment {
    width:470px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #f0f0f0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.comment:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

That does not work as long as I do have another `div.something` as actual last child in the commentList. Is it possible to use the last-child selector in this case to select the last appearance of `article.comment`?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/2/)

Comment: linked: [select the “last child” with a specific class name in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6401268/104380)

Answer (score 303, accepted):

`:last-child` only works when the element in question is the last child of the container, not the last of a specific type of element. For that, you want [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)

http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/3/

As per @BoltClock's comment, this is only checking for the last `article` element, not the last element with the class of `.comment`.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.comment {
  width: 470px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #f0f0f0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.comment:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="commentList">
  <article class="comment " id="com21"></article>

  <article class="comment " id="com20"></article>

  <article class="comment " id="com19"></article>

  <div class="something"> hello </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not look at the class though, only the type, so if you happen to have non-articles with the same class you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: It works properly. However, if we need them to narrow down elements by class, it does not work again. http://jsfiddle.net/aliemreeee/a4H7f/2/

Comment: based on these answers, I presume that there is no way to select `last-of-class`.

Comment: not until CSS selectors level 4 is accepted and implemented by browsers, where you will have access to `:nth-match(selector)` and `:nth-last-match(selector)`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/ for more detail.

Comment: Or rather, `:nth-last-child(An+B of selector)`, as `:nth-last-match()` was dropped long before that, but they haven't bothered to update the WD. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167159/css-nth-match-doesnt-work/31415015#31415015

Comment: Replace article with a div and this fails.

Comment: @AndroidDev It doesn't fail, it just changes which element gets targeted.

Comment: `:nth-child(An+b of S)` is not implemented in any browser except for Safari (https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of)

Comment: That doesn't work with tables, unless I applied it wrongly, but I'm sure I did not

Comment: Using `:last-of-type` against a class doesn't target the last element with a class, but rather the last element of a certain type that has the class. I.e. it does NOT act as a `:last-of-class` selector. The best solution is to therefore use the `:has` selector as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75200868/165673)

Answer (score 33):

This can now be solved with careful use of `:has()`, specifically:

```css
/* switch out the {class} below */
.{class}:not(:has(~ .{class}))
```

A similar technique also allows you to select anything *but* the last occurrence of a class in a container, or the last occurrence within a group of elements. See the snippet below for examples.

**Note: `has()` is currently supported in Chrome, Edge, Safari & Firefox [since at least Dec 2023](https://caniuse.com/css-has)**

```css
/* last in group */
.class:has(+ :not(.class)) {
  background: pink;
}
/* anything but last in container */
.class:has(~ .class) {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #F00A;
}
/* last in container */
.class:not(:has(~ .class)) {
  background: #0F0A;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="class">not-last</div>
   <div class="class">not-last</div>
   <div class="class">last-in-group</div>
   <div>---</div>
   <div class="class">not-last</div>
   <div class="class">last-in-group</div>
   <div>---</div>
   <div class="class">last-class</div>
   <div>---</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is supported on Firefox now : https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 18):

I guess that the most correct answer is: Use `:nth-child` (or, in this specific case, its counterpart `:nth-last-child`). Most only know this selector by its first argument to grab a range of items based on a calculation with n, but it can also take a second argument "of [any CSS selector]".

Your scenario could be solved with this selector: `.commentList .comment:nth-last-child(1 of .comment)`

But being technically correct doesn't mean you can use it, though, because this selector is as of now only implemented in Safari.

For further reading:

- https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo
- http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Answer (score 9):

The new `:has()` pseudo class (not yet supported by all browsers) lets you get pretty close to a solution:

```
.class:has(+ :not(.class))
```

The limitation is that this will find any element with `.class` which is followed by an element that doesn't have this class. But this would match the use case of the question.

Comment: fyi I dropped in a solution below using `:has` that works (you need to switch your `:not` and `:has`)

Comment: Ah, so close ... :-) Great that this is finally possible with CSS.

Answer (score 8):

If you are floating the elements you can reverse the order

i.e. `float: right;` instead of `float: left;`

And then use this method to select the first-child of a class.

```
/* 1: Apply style to ALL instances */
#header .some-class {
  padding-right: 0;
}
/* 2: Remove style from ALL instances except FIRST instance */
#header .some-class~.some-class {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

This is actually applying the class to the LAST instance only because it's now in reversed order.

Here is a working example for you:

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title>CSS Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.some-class { margin: 0; padding: 0 20px; list-style-type: square; }
.lfloat { float: left; display: block; }
.rfloat { float: right; display: block; }
/* apply style to last instance only */
#header .some-class {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#header .some-class~.some-class {
  border: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
  <img src="some_image" title="Logo" class="lfloat no-border"/>
  <ul class="some-class rfloat">
    <li>List 1-1</li>
    <li>List 1-2</li>
    <li>List 1-3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="some-class rfloat">
    <li>List 2-1</li>
    <li>List 2-2</li>
    <li>List 2-3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="some-class rfloat">
    <li>List 3-1</li>
    <li>List 3-2</li>
    <li>List 3-3</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="some_other_img" title="Icon" class="rfloat no-border"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note though this won't work if the floating elements are pushed onto the next line (i.e. not enough horizontal space to float-right/left)

Comment: `.some-class~.some-class` works great for me when only 2 elements repeated.

Answer (score 8):

This works fine in all major browsers;

```css
    /* target first element with class ".comment" */
    :nth-child(1 of .comment) {
        background-color: red;
    }

    /* target last element with class ".comment" */
    :nth-last-child(1 of .comment) {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="commentList">
 <div class="something"> hello </div>
 <article class="comment " id="com21">test</article>
 <article class="comment " id="com20">test</article>
 <article class="comment " id="com19">test</article>
 <div class="something"> hello </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like regular CSS, are you using Preprocessor like Sass or Less?

Comment: But it's vanilla CSS :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#the_of_selector_syntax

Answer (score 7):

Something that I think should be commented here that worked for me:

Use `:last-child` multiple times in the places needed so that it always gets the last of the last.

Take this for example:

```css
.page.one .page-container .comment:last-child {
  color: red;
}
.page.two .page-container:last-child .comment:last-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p> When you use .comment:last-child </p>
<p> you only get the last comment in both parents </p>

<div class="page one">
  <div class="page-container">
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
  </div>

  <div class="page-container">
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
  </div>
</div>

<p> When you use .page-container:last-child .comment:last-child </p>
<p> you get the last page-container's, last comment </p>

<div class="page two">
  <div class="page-container">
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
  </div>

  <div class="page-container">
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
    <p class="comment"> Something </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped. I have one question though. Why does ```.page.one .page-container:last-child``` not point to last child ? Why should we add comment also in the list of classes ?

Comment: @Bharat It's hard to explain but I'll try my best. There's a hierarchy here; The `page` is the parent, `page-container`'s are the children, and the `comment`'s are the grandchildren. If you just do `.page.one .page-container:last-child` then you're getting the last child that has the class `page-container`, and not the last child that has the class `comment` because that was never specified. When using `:last-child` is doesn't look INSIDE the selected element for the last child, it looks AT the selected element to see if it's the last child. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution?

```
div.commentList > article.comment:not(:last-child):last-of-type
{
    color:red; /*or whatever...*/
}
```

Comment: @lsblsb, You use `article` here, so :not(:last-child) is not necessary for given example.

Comment: what if the element with class `something` doesn't exist in original HTML and is being inserted dynamically on `hover`? Won't this solution fail?