# CSS selector code last element

Tags: css, selector

Need help guys I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="editable">
  <div>
     <div class="column col1of5">
     </div>
     <div class="column col1of5"> 
     </div>
     <div class="column col1of5"> 
     </div>
     <div class="column col1of5">
     </div>
     <div class="column col1of5">  
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I want to select the last .col1of5 through css how can I do that?

Comment: Where is your html code ?

Comment: Calm down guys he didn't indent it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS to get the last child :

```
.parentDiv .col1of5:last-child {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Comment: Nesting selectors and rules? That's new.

Comment: The OP didn't say he uses Compass, which is a framework that is not natively implemented in browsers. Your code is invalid as it stands. This question is not tagged [tag:Compass].

Comment: Compass is just a way to build CSS more easily. But you're right, it's my fault, just the habits...

Answer (score 2):

I just saw your HTML.

Here is the solution. refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tAJn/1/).

The HTML

```
<div class="editable">
  <div>
     <div class="column col1of5">1</div>
     <div class="column col1of5">2</div>
     <div class="column col1of5">3</div>
     <div class="column col1of5">4</div>
     <div class="column col1of5">5</div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS

```
.editable div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #292929;
    color: white;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
.editable div div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid #3C3C3C;
    padding: 10px;
}
.editable div div:first-child {
    border-top: medium none;
}
.editable div div:last-child {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    color: red;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.col1of5:last-child {
    /* my CSS rules */
}
```

`:last-child` is a pseudo selector and it points to the element that is the last child element of a certain node. It may sound logical enough but it can be confusing, since you may think it should be `.editable:last-child`. You should apply the selector to the **child** element itself, not the parent.