# How do I select the “last child” of element with specific class name in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a HTML table and I want the last row, excluding the row with class `.table-bottom`, and remove its `border-bottom`:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:752px;" class="table">
    <tr class="table-top"><th style="width:40px;">ID</th> <th>Post title</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Owner</th> <th style="width:100px;">Actions</th></tr>
    <tr class="table-middle"><td>1</td> <td>Test</td> <td>16.7.2013</td> <td>Admin</td> <td>Delete</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-middle"><td>2</td> <td>Test 2</td> <td>3.8.2013</td> <td>Admin</td> <td>Delete</td></tr>
    <tr class="table-bottom"><td colspan="5"></td></tr>
</table>
```

```css
.table tr th {
color:#929191;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14px;
text-align:left;
padding-left:19px;
border-right:1px solid #d7d7d7;
border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
.table tr th:last-child {
border-right:none;
}
.table tr td {
color:#929191;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
padding:19px;
border-right:1px solid #d7d7d7;
border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
.table tr td:last-child {
border-right:none;
}
.table .table-middle:last-of-type td {
border-bottom:none;
background:red;
}
.table tr.table-middle td:first-child {
text-align:center;
}
.table tr th:first-child {
text-align:center;
padding-left:0px;
}
.table tr.table-bottom td {
border-right:none;
border-bottom:none;
}
```

But the `.table .table-middle:last-of-type td` selector is not working.

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VAqSw/)**.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can also find similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298062/1725764

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** you can't do it by CSS, unless you change your HTML structure.

**More detail:**

[`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) pseudo-class, represents the element which is the last sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

Consider this selector: `.table-middle:last-of-type`.

while `.table-middle` points the element correctly, the element that has `.table-middle` class is NOT the last sibling of its `type`, because the term of `type` refers to the HTML element itself, not combination of `element.class`.

---

Here is the working solution:

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:752px;" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:40px;">ID</th>
            <th>Post title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th style="width:100px;">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>16.7.2013</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
            <td>3.8.2013</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.table tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom:none;
    background:red;
}
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/VAqSw/1/)**

Comment: Using tfoot when that last row appears to have a colspan is an excellent advice.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it much simpler without using classes at all:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 500px;
}
table td {  /* style for all the cells between the top and bottom row */
    background: red;
}
table tr:first-child td { /* style for the cells in the top row */
    background: green;
}
table tr:last-child td { /* style for the cells in the bottom row */
    background: blue;
}
table tr:first-child td:first-child, /* first row, first cell */
table tr:first-child td:last-child, /* first row, last cell */
table tr:last-child td:first-child, /* last row, first cell */
table tr:last-child td:last-child { /* last row, last cell */
    background: yellow;
}
```

Also check the [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/AcTkP/).

Comment: It doesn't help to select the last `.table-middle` table row.

Comment: That's true. But since the last table row in the code from the startpost, I think it isn't needed. But that's up to the TS to decide.