# :last-child not working as expected?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The issue lies within this CSS and HTML. Here is a [link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nejj/W8arF/) with the sample code.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class"complete">1</li>
    <li class"complete">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li.complete:last-child {
    background-color:yellow;
}

li.complete:last-of-type {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Shouldn't either of these lines of CSS target the **last li element with the "complete" class**?

This query in jQuery doesn't target it either:

```
$("li.complete:last-child");
```

But this one does:

```
$("li.complete").last();
```

```css
li {
  background-color: green;
}
li.complete:first-child {
  background-color: white;
}
li.complete:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
li.complete:last-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
}
li.complete:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="complete">1</li>
  <li class="complete">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans What do you mean? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ or more specifically http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select the last element with a specific class, not last child inside of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/how-can-i-select-the-last-element-with-a-specific-class-not-last-child-inside-o)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The `last-child` selector is used to select the last child element of a parent. It cannot be used to select the last child element with a specific class under a given parent element.

The other part of the compound selector (which is attached before the `:last-child`) specifies extra conditions which the last child element must satisfy in-order for it to be selected. In the below snippet, you would see how the selected elements differ depending on the rest of the compound selector.

```css
.parent :last-child{ /* this will select all elements which are last child of .parent */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.parent div:last-child{ /* this will select the last child of .parent only if it is a div*/
  background: crimson;
}

.parent div.child-2:last-child{ /* this will select the last child of .parent only if it is a div and has the class child-2*/
  color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div>Child w/o class</div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div class='child-2'>Child w/o class</div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <div class='child'>Child</div>
  <p>Child w/o class</p>
</div>
```

---

To answer your question, the below would style the last child `li` element with background color as red.

```
li:last-child{
    background-color: red;
}
```

But the following selector would not work for your markup because the `last-child` does not have the `class='complete'` even though it is an `li`.

```
li.complete:last-child{
    background-color: green;
}
```

It would have worked if (and only if) the last `li` in your markup also had `class='complete'`.

---

To address your query in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected/18995451#comment28062166_18995451):

> @Harry I find it rather odd that: .complete:last-of-type does not work, yet .complete:first-of-type does work, regardless of it's position it's parents element. Thanks for your help.

The selector `.complete:first-of-type` works in the fiddle because it (that is, the element with `class='complete'`) is still the first element of type `li` within the parent. Try to add `<li>0</li>` as the first element under the `ul` and you will find that `first-of-type` also flops. This is because the `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` selectors select the first/last element of each type under the parent.

Refer to the answer posted by BoltClock, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) thread for more details about how the selector works. That is as comprehensive as it gets :)

Comment: This is so silly but I think you're right. Hopefully they add this to the CSS4 spec.

Comment: @NejKutcharian: Yes, I think it has been in proposal for a long time.

Comment: @Harry I find it rather odd that: .complete:last-of-type does not work, yet .complete:first-of-type does work, regardless of it's position it's parents element. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NejKutcharian: Ok got it. `.complete:first-of-type` works in the fiddle because it is still the first element of type `li` within the parent. Try to add `<li>0</li>` as the first element under `li` and you will find that `first-of-type` also flops.

Answer (score 193):

### `:last-child` will not work if the element is not the VERY LAST element

I think it's crucial to add/emphasize that `:last-child` will not work if the element is not the VERY LAST element in a container. For whatever reason it took me hours to realize that, and even though Harry's answer is very thorough I couldn't extract that information from *"The last-child selector is used to select the last child element of a parent."*

Suppose this is my selector: `a:last-child {}`

This works:

```
<div>
    <a></a>
    <a>This will be selected</a>
</div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div>
    <a></a>
    <a>This will no longer be selected</a>
    <div>This is now the last child :'( </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't because the `a` element is not the last element inside its parent.

It may be obvious, but it was not for me...

---

**Sidebar**: This may seem like a ridiculous gotcha, but the devil's always in the details. [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) may fit your needs in most cases (and feels intuitive) but `:last-child` definitely serves a purpose. It offers greater specificity (targeting only those elements which are, in-fact, the very last child in a parent). It depends on your use-case.

Comment: Double man! Also, nth-last-child works the same. Use last-of-type instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info, it helped me figure out why my CSS wasn't working. I'm sure the sticklers would argue this is correct, but I sure wish the pseuoclass was last-child of the selector you're modifying, and didn't only work on last child of the whole node list.

Comment: This helped me. I had three labels and a @Html.ValidationMessageFor for the input and the last child was the ValidationMessage...

Comment: This is super useful. I spent hours trying to get my li:last-child working, but it was followed by div. last-of-type worked for me

Comment: After struggling with this issue for a while, I searched stackoverflow where I saw this answer, which already had an orange upvote. Seems like this is not the first time you've helped me out haha

Comment: @Robin I have that same experience on StackOverflow **_all_** the time. :D

Answer (score 20):

I encounter similar situation. I would like to have background of the last `.item` to be yellow in the elements that look like...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  ...
  <div class="item">item x</div>
  <div class="other">I'm here for some reasons</div>
</div>
```

I use `nth-last-child(2)` to achieve it.

```
.item:nth-last-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

It strange to me because nth-last-child of item suppose to be the second of the last item but it works and I got the result as I expect.
I found this helpful trick from [CSS Trick](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)