# :last-child not working when I add elements after it

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code that consists of 5 uls in a div. I also have a piece of CSS that changes the last child's bottom margin. I have `#divid ul:lastchild{margin-bottom: 10px;}`, and it works, but when I add more divs after the last ul it doesn't.

```html
<div id="divid">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

```css
#divid ul:lastchild {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `last-of-type` if you wan't to style last `ul` no matter if it's actually the last element within its parent.

```
#divid ul:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```