# :last-child / last-of-type pseudo difficulties

Tags: css

Having difficulty trying to target a particular element in a set that is the last matching selector.

```
<div class="items">
    <article class="today">
        this is today
    </article>
    <article class="today">
        this is today
    </article>
    <article class="today">
        this is today
    </article>
    <article>
        Not today
    </article>
    <article>
        Not today
    </article>
</div>
```

My goal is to re-style the last item `article.today`.

```
article {
    background: cyan;
}

.today:last-child { 
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

it does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/nv54h/ 
changing to:

```
article {
    background: cyan;
}

article:last-child { 
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

does work in that last item is now black. http://jsfiddle.net/nv54h/1/ - but without doing two loops or different elements, I can't get it to work as expected (via eg, `last-of-type`)

is there any way you can think of targetting the last `.today` item only? list is generated via iteration of a collection on the fly that changes in real time so a CSS/markup only solution would be perfect, avoiding logic and back references if item `n+1` not `today` etc. I guess `:last` in Sizzle is an ideal solution but...

Comment: `:last-child` applies only for elements and not classes and hence the first option doesn't work :) You can refer to my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/css-last-child-not-working-as-expected/18995451#18995451) or BoltClock's answer I have linked in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is with javascript...

`:last-child` and `:last-of-type` only work on elements, they don't pay attention to classes in the way you are thinking they should.  By removing the two articles without a class name your code then works...

http://jsfiddle.net/nv54h/2/

---

Using some jQuery you can achieve this easily:

```
$( "article.today:last" ).css({ backgroundColor: "yellow", fontWeight: "bolder" });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nv54h/3/

---

Better yet, just add a class.  This way, all your styles can remain in your style sheet.

```
$( "article.today:last" ).addClass('black');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nv54h/4/

Comment: …but even when using JS, please set classes instead of inline stylesheets. That way you may edit all the required CSS in one place.

Comment: yeah I ended up decorating the last element matching with a class. it's not ideal but it works.