# Apply CSS to last element of specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply some CSS to the last blog-post. The problem is that the last element in the div 'blog-posts' is the same type of element as the 'blog-post' divs.

I've tried:

- last-of-type
- last-child

HTML:

```
<div class="blog-posts">
    <div class="blog-post"></div>
    <div class="blog-post"></div>
    <div class="blog-post"></div>
    <div class="blog-post"></div>
    <div class="f03-456245"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blog-post:last-child{
    //do some css
}
```

Comment: `last-child` doesn't work that way. It only selects the element which is the last child and not the last child with a certain class. In this case it would do nothing because the last-child doesn't have the `blog-post` class. You can find more info in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/css-last-child-not-working-as-expected/18995451#18995451).

Comment: If you have always the same number of div can use .blog-posts div:nth-child(4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS last-child selector: select last-element of specific class, not last child inside of parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i)

Comment: Another option could be to actually use a list for your "list" of blog articles. http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/quumnr6h/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Last element using `.class` is not possible. In your case you can use `nth-last-child` property.

```
 .blog-posts div:nth-last-child(2) {
   background: #ff0000;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/09hdke93/2/)

Comment: but this solution only highlights second last element instead of last element of particular class

Comment: You are correct. According to his mockup i have given my solution.

Answer (score -3):

You may have to do like this:

```
.blog-posts div:last-child{
  //do some css
}
```

It is assuming `div` is the element. It applies for anyother element type `p` , `span` etc...