# Comma-separated spans with pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have - let's say - 4 spans on my page in a block. The content of each is populated by knockout from my viewmodel. Sometimes contents are empty for several spans. I would like to display them in a nice, comma-separated way, taking possible emptyness into account.

I tried the following HTML and CSS.

VERSION 1

It shows commas for empty spans as well

```css
.comma:not(:last-child):after {
  content: ", ";
}
```

```html
<span class="comma">A</span>
<span class="comma">B</span>
<span class="comma"></span>
<span class="comma">D</span>
```

VERSION 2

It shows a (visually) last comma if last span is empty.

```css
.comma:not(:empty):not(:last-child):after {
  content: ", ";
}
```

```html
<span class="comma">A</span>
<span class="comma">B</span>
<span class="comma">C</span>
<span class="comma"></span>
```

How could I tweak it to render always correctly, no matter where the gaps are (if any)?
I need to support only modern browsers (IE9+ and others).

Comment: What format do you exactly require A,B,C,D?

Comment: Your second solution seems to work fine for me on fiddle?

Comment: Oh, no, wait it doesn't.

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27837306/404335

Comment: Thank you everyone for your efforts, the answer from @FabrizioCalderan looks the most promising currently.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I reversed the logic, placing the comma as the content of `before` pseudoelement and I managed the case where also the first span can be empty.

```css
.comma:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -.3em;  
}

.comma:first-child:empty ~ .comma:not(:empty) {
  margin-left: 0;  
}

.comma:first-child:empty ~ .comma:not(:empty) ~ .comma:not(:empty) {
  margin-left: -.3em;  
}

.comma:empty {
  display: none;
}

.comma:not(:first-child):before {
  content: ", ";
}

.comma:empty + .comma:not(:empty):before {
  content : "";
}

.comma:not(:empty) ~ .comma:empty + .comma:not(:empty):before {
  content : ", ";
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<hr />

<div>
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma">A</span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">B</span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma">C</span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">D</span>
</div>

<hr />
All empty:
<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span> 
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>
```

---

Further information about `:empty` pseudoclass available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Comment: Nice, but you cheated, you hidden the empty ones ;)

Comment: well `:empty` is supported from IE9 so it seems legit :D

Comment: This does assume the first span is not empty, right?

Comment: that's because last-child is used to select the last child element of a parent element. It cannot be used to select the last child element with a specific class under a given parent element. [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/css-last-child-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Thanks, this looks the most promising I think, I'm gonna test it soon.

Answer (score 7):

Switch it round. Instead of putting a comma after your spans, put it *before* each span which is preceded (any distance back!) by a non-empty span:

```
.comma:not(:empty) ~ .comma:not(:empty):before {
  content: ", ";
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s18wmdd/)

Comment: This leaves that ugly space.

Comment: Combining this with Fabrizio's `margin-left: -.3em;` should do the trick.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle not if you don't have spaces between html tags ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p4x70h8/)).
This is just how HTML [works](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xtrabhwh/3/

```
<span class="comma">A</span><span class="comma">B</span><span class="comma">C</span><span class="comma"></span>

.comma ~ .comma:not(:empty):before {
    content: ", ";
}
```

Comment: The reason the <spans> are all on the one line is otherwise there is a space added after each span (where the nl character is).

Answer (score 0):

The below should do it, for just about any combination, without hiding anything.

```css
.comma:before {
  content: ','
}
.comma:empty:before,
.comma:first-of-type:before,
.comma:first-of-type+.comma:empty:before,
.comma:empty+.comma:not(:last-of-type):before,
.comma:empty+.comma:empty:before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<h4>Missing first</h4>
<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
</div>
<h4>Missing last</h4>
<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
</div>
<h4>Missing first two</h4>
<div>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
</div>
<h4>Missing last two</h4>
<div>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
</div>
<h4>Missing middle</h4>
<div>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
</div>
<h4>Missing middle two</h4>
<div>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma"></span>
  <span class="comma">item</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is clean but an extra comma appears when last two elements are empty

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - see revision, and use cases - the revised rule passes each

Comment: Nice but... almost: if you have only D an extra comma still appears. Good job anyway.