# CSS unable to select last-child of p element

Tags: css

I have a container with several `p` elements and several `input` elements. I need to select the last `p` element inside this container, and for some reason I'm not able to. I've tried several methods but non seem to work. It must be `last-child` and not `nth-child` since there might be more elements in the future. Whats the difference between `last-of-type` and `p:last-child`?

JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h51rcmag/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="inputContainer">
    <p class="contact_title">EMAIL</p>
    <p>john@snow</p>
    <p class="contact_title">PHONE</p>
    <p>123-hodor-hodor</p>
    <p class="contact_title">ADDRESS</p>
    <p>castle black</p>
    <input id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="phone" type="number" placeholder="Phone">
    <textarea id="note" placeholder="bla bla"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* not working 1 */
 #inputContainer :last-of-type p {
    color: red !important;
}
/* not working 2
 #inputContainer > p:last-child {
    color: red !important;
}
not working 3
 #inputContainer p:last-child {
    color: red !important;
} */
```

Comment: You need `#inputContainer p:last-of-type`. `last-child` doesn't work the way you are expecting it to. Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected/18995451#18995451) for details on how it works.

Comment: ohh sorry Harry, i did not read your comment and was working on fiddle..you already gave answer before me..ty

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h51rcmag/3/ updated  working fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use css selectors in this way..it will work. use p before last of type..or else it won't work.

```
#inputContainer p:last-of-type {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 2):

:last-of-type is the last element of this specific type...
So p:last-of-type would be the last p element amond all the siblings.

:last-child only triggers if it really is the last child

```
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Here the second <p> would trigger p:last-child, because it is the last child of the <div> element

```
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <img />
</div>
```

Here p:last-child would not trigger, because neither of the 2 <p> are the last child of it's parent, in fact the last child is an <img>
p:last-of-type would be triggered by the 2nd <p> though, because that is the last <p> among all 3 siblings