# Last child with specific class

Tags: html, css

I have a case when the `HTML` is being generated dynamically using `JS`.

I want to apply some styles for given code for specific class. The problem is I can't change `HTML` syntax, because it is an external resource returned into my client app.

In case:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="c1" />
   <div class="c1" />
   <div class="c1" />
   <div class="c1" /> // this one should be selected
</div>
```

In other case:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="c1" />
   <div class="c1" />
   <div class="c1" />
   <div class="c1" /> // this one should be selected
   <div class="c2" />
</div>
```

In other words, I want to select the last child within `parent` block that contains `chosen-css-class`.

I tried `:last-of-type`, but it doesn't work for classes. Is it possible to solve this issue using `CSS` only?

Also tried to find something on Web, but wasn't lucky too much...

Comment: You definitely need JS for this. Neither `last-child` nor `last-of-type` would work here. In the second case, the `div` with class `c1` is neither the last child of the parent nor is it the last element of its type within the parent. You can find some information on how it works here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected/18995451#18995451

Comment: Please, convert your comment into an answer. I will mark it with a green tick.