# How to remove border for the last div with a particular class name? [:last-child] is not working

Tags: css

I tried removing border for the last-child with class name "true". `:last-child` is not working.

```
<div>
    <div class="common true">1111</div>
    <div class="common">2222</div>
    <div class="common true">3333</div>
    <div class="common true">4444</div>
    <div class="common true">5555</div>
    <div class="common true">6666</div>
    <div class="common true">7777</div>
    <div class="common">8888</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.common.true {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid;
} 

.true:last-child {
    border-top: none;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/1253/

Comment: CSS has no selector to select the last element with a specific class. It has only `last-child` and `last-of-type`. Neither works for this case. You need to use JS. (Related threads - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected/18995451#18995451 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107).

Comment: I haven't voted to close as dupes just in-case you want to edit and accept JS/jQuery answers.

Comment: if you can then add a class in your last true element  <div class="common true last">7777</div>  and the css .common.true.last{ border-top: 0 none; }

Answer (score 5):

You should use js to resolve it. With css you can use `last-child` or `last-of-type`, but in this case, they can't resolve the problem, because:

> The :last-child selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent.

in your case `.true` isn't the last child

and

> The :last-of-type selector matches every element that is the last child, **of a particular type**, of its parent.

in your case all elements are `div` and you can't select the div with specific class with `last-of-type`

you can try:

```
$(".true").last().css( "border-top", "none" );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/1254/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want to use CSS. Is there any way to do it in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The `:last-of-type` selector allows you to target the last occurence of an element within its container.

```
.true:last-of-type {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: :last-of-type selector only selects elements not classes

Comment: `.true:last-of-type` means it select last element with true class

Comment: .true is a class not an element, that is why it doesn't work. p:last-of-type or div:last-of-type would all work not .true:last-of-type