# How to insert row after last row with a certain class with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Given the following table:

```
    <table>
        <tr class="one"><td>Hello</td></tr>
        <tr class="one"><td>Hello</td></tr>
        <tr class="one"><td>Hello</td></tr>
        <tr class="two"><td>World</td></tr>
        <tr class="two"><td>World</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Is it possible to use JQuery to insert a row between the 3rd and 4th rows (when the class changes from "one" to "two")? If so, how?

I'm thinking maybe using insertAfter() and .last() in some combination...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('table tr:nth-child(3)').after('<div>....</div>');
```

This will insert something after the 3rd row every time!

```
$('table .one:nth-child(3)').after('<div>....</div>');
```

This will insert something after the 3rd `.one` class.

```
$('table .two:nth-child(1)').before('<div>....</div>');
```

This would insert before the first `.two` class. Meaning it would be inbetween `.one` & `.two`.

### Edit

From what I understand of your comment, you would like to insert an element after the last `.one` `tr`.

This can easily be done by using this:

```
$('.one').last().after('<div>...code goes in here...</div>');
```

OR

```
$('.one:last-child').after('<div>...</div>');
```

Comment: I would like to be able to dynamically add the row

Comment: Wait, so do you want to insert something after every 3'rd row? @elemenop

Comment: I would like to add another <tr class="one"><td>Hello</td></tr> after the 3rd row, but I'd like to be able to keep adding more of the same rows. Each new <tr class="one"><td>Hello</td></tr> will be inserted after the last row with the class "one"

Comment: @James111 I just discovered that `$('.one:last-child')` doesn't work as expected. It only works if the `.one` is actually the last child element of the parent, and not just the last child with a class.

Answer (score 1):

Easy if you do it like this, my opinion!

```
$("table").find(".one").eq(-1).after($("<tr><td>").text("circle of life"))
```

- *find() , finds all elements with class .one *
- *eq(-1) , least element *
- *after() , places the object after your eq(-1) element*
- *($("") , makes the object *
- *text() , set the text of the object*

```js
$("table").find(".one").eq(-1).after($("<tr><td>").text("circle of life"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="one">
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>World</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this.

```
$('table .one:last-child').after(your html here)
```

EDIT: I seemed to have stumbled across a common misunderstanding of the `last-child` selector. If you're curious about why my answer doesn't work read this. [:last-child not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected)

The corrected answer is `$('table .one:last').after(your html here)`

Comment: It works if you only do `.one:last` instead of `.one:last-child`, though i'm not sure why...

Comment: I meant i didn't understand why `:last-child` wasn't working, but now i have some idea.