# How to use JQuery .append() method to add a string containing html?

Tags: jquery, html, append

I created a html page with a search form and I want to show a table with some data whenever the user clicks on the Search button.

I want to use JQuery to show such data instead than inserting a static html `<tr>`. I want to exploit the `.append()` method to add a string containing the `<td>` with data.

So I did the following:

I copypasted a bootstrap code for table and emptied the `<tbody>`, so the table won't show any row if results will not be returned.

I gave an ID to the `<tbody>`

This is the html code:

```
<table id="tabella" class="table hide">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">Cognome</th>
      <th scope="col">Indirizzo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
<!-- 

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Maria</td>
      <td>Ottone</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Giacomo</td>
      <td>Troisi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Lorenza</td>
      <td>Pieri</td>
    </tr>

 <-->

  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need to do now is appending the first `<tr>` of the table (previuìously deleted) to the `<tbody>` by using the JQuery `.append()` method, as if it were a string, by selecting the ID of the `<tbody>`.

```
function validateNome(){
  console.log('function validateNome has been activated');

  if ($("#inlineFormInputNome").val()=="") {
      $("#errorLog").show();    
  } else {          
    $("#errorLog").hide();    
    $("#cercaNome").prop("disabled", true);     
    setTimeout(function (){              
      $("#tabella").show();
```

//What should I write inside the parentheses in the following line?

```
      $("#tbody").append("        ");

       $("#cercaNome").prop("disabled", false);    
    } , 2000);
  }
}
```

That's to say: is it possible to combine the `append()` method with the `html()` method in JQuery?
Or:
How may I use JQuery `.append()` method to add a string containing `html` code?

Comment: Just FYI, you'll get more accurate answers more quickly if you show us the actual code instead of describing it

Comment: You can check this post if it helps in anyway:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append

Comment: @addo.lou thank you for suggesting it. Let's say that I'm trying to "fill that html() method inside the append() method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 $("#tabella tbody").append('<tr><th scope="row">2</th><td>Giacomo</td><td>Troisi</td>/tr>');
```

It will appened the `<tr>` after the last `<tr>` that's in the table.

Comment: thank you! I tried to do that before but I left the spaces into the code; now, by looking at your snippet, I deleted the spaces between the tags and it works!

Comment: You're welcome! I also leave you this other post, might come in handy some other time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974058/how-to-insert-row-after-last-row-with-a-certain-class-with-jquery