# no space between childs in class in css

Tags: html, css

I have this code in html

```html
<div class="small_world_news">
  <div class="small_world_news_article_box">
    <div>
      <img class="small_picture_world_news" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <h4 class="small_title_world_news"> Doors open to Japan's new 30B industry </h4>
      <ul class="author_etc">
        <li>December 14, 2016</li>
        <li>
          <div class="first">by</div>
          <div class="blue">John Doe</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="small_picture_world_news" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <h4 class="small_title_world_news"> Doors open to Japan's new 30B industry </h4>
      <ul class="author_etc">
        <li>December 14, 2016</li>
        <li>
          <div class="first">by</div>
          <div class="blue">John Doe</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="small_picture_world_news" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <h4 class="small_title_world_news"> Doors open to Japan's new 30B industry </h4>
      <ul class="author_etc">
        <li>December 14, 2016</li>
        <li>
          <div class="first">by</div>
          <div class="blue">John Doe</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I need `20px` space between firstarticle-secondarticle and secondarticle-thirdarticle. Also I need `30px` space after last article. I know that I can make named divs, but I want to with child of class "small_world_news_Article_box".
But this code doesent work.

```css
.small_world_news_article_box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.small_world_news_article_box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:last-child not working as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.small_world_news_article_box > div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.small_world_news_article_box > div:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I still have not  20px space between dirst-second and second-third

Comment: codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/ZeXbNY I addeed rest of my css code. Probbably mistake in this

Comment: Sorry now i hope, that it si correct. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWMowL

Comment: Yes, you need to add `overflow: hidden;` to your `.small_world_news_article_box > div` style cause your picture is float and bigger than your div. And `margin-bottom: 0;` to your `ul`.

Answer (score 2):

Target the child div of the class like so:

```
.small_world_news_article_box>div {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.small_world_news_article_box>div:last-child{
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/ZeXbNY

Clearfix:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
} 
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I still have not  20px space between dirst-second and second-third

Comment: http://codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/ZeXbNY

I addeed rest of my css code. Probbably mistake in this

Comment: Sorry now i hope, that it si correct. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWMowL

Comment: try adding the clearfix class to divs using the css edited.

Answer (score 0):

:last-child works on the element theres a few of not the containing element.

In your case the unnamed div the article is contained in is what you need to apply the class to. So what you need is:

```
.small_world_news_article_box > div{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.small_world_news_article_box > div:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

You can read more about how it all works here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

Comment: I still have not  20px space between dirst-second and second-third

Comment: codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/ZeXbNY I addeed rest of my css code. Probbably mistake in this

Comment: It's really subtle - but if you change the css values as I've done here you can see it does work - http://codepen.io/WebDevelopWolf/pen/WpZrdN

Comment: Sorry now i hope, that it si correct. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWMowL

Comment: Try it now - I've changed it above - put that in the code pen and it will work :) - http://codepen.io/WebDevelopWolf/pen/OpxNJP

Comment: Thank for help, but i addet overflow in my code pen and still no change :/

Comment: You were missing a : (colon) - http://codepen.io/WebDevelopWolf/pen/QpqEvV