# CSS : get last HTML tag with a given class, in a list where not every HTML tag has this class

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

**THIS IS A DUPLICATE OF MY [CLOSED QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524290/css-selector-after-pseudo-element-of-the-last-item-of-a-list-with-a-given-clas), BUT THE DUPLICATES ARE IRRELEVANT**

[First "duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i)

> It does not look at the class though, only the type, so if you happen to have non-articles with the same class you'll get unexpected results

[Second "duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector) is entirely something else.

[Third "duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected) is the explanation of why my try didn't work.

[Fourth "duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) gives a workaround for the first element, not the last.

**I have understood that there is no CSS selector for that, I juste want a solution. Be mindful of that before closing my question !**

---

I have 5 buttons. They have an underlayer that make them seem they are active, as you will see in the snippet.

Each button can have an active state, but only starting from 1, and ending anywhere to 5.

They all have a divider, displayed in red in the snippet.

I would like to keep the divider into the underlayer, outside of the underlayer, but I would like to make it disappear at the end of the underlayer (in snippet, after button #2).

Following my first question, I understood that there is no CSS selector to do that. So what would be the best way to tackle this issue ?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: start
  margin: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  left: calc(100% + 12px);
  width: 1px;
  top: 0;
}

button.active:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 calc(20% - 24px);
  border: 0;
  height: 32px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 24px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

button.active {
  color: white;
}

.active-pill {
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: teal;
  width: calc(40% - 12px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="active-pill"></div>
  
  <button class="active">Step 1</button>
  <button class="active">Step 2</button>
  <button>Step 3</button>
  <button>Step 4</button>
  <button>Step 5</button>
</div>

<h3>
  Which selector to use to remove the content after button #2 ?
</h3>
```

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the buttons on a div and play around this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: @M4FI4S because the issue would still be the same, I would then have to find `div.active`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case: Just put the divider on the left side of the buttons, instead of the right?

Then the one that *doesn’t* need one, becomes the first non-active one after the active ones, so it can easily be selected using `button.active + button:not(.active):after`

The first button here technically has a divider to the left as well then, that gets cut off here when the snippet gets rendered anyway. But in a situation where you’d need to explicitly “eliminate” it, you could still go with just plain and simple `:first-child` here (I’m assuming if there’s active buttons, it always starts with the first one, right?)

This is a bit similar to what Hao suggested in their answer, but with their version, the divider gets placed on the right on some buttons, on the left on others … I’d prefer to simply have it the same on all.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: start
  margin: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  right: calc(100% + 12px);
  width: 1px;
  top: 0;
}

button.active + button:not(.active):after {
  content: none;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 calc(20% - 24px);
  border: 0;
  height: 32px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 24px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

button.active {
  color: white;
}

.active-pill {
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: teal;
  width: calc(40% - 12px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="active-pill"></div>
  
  <button class="active">Step 1</button>
  <button class="active">Step 2</button>
  <button>Step 3</button>
  <button>Step 4</button>
  <button>Step 5</button>
</div>

<h3>
  Which selector to use to remove the content after button #2 ?
</h3>
```

Comment: This one is indeed better

Comment: Indeed, this is CSS only and fullfills my requirements ! Thank you for that, I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in pure css there is no way to select the last element with a specific class.

There are loads of possible solutions to your issue however. To name a few:

1. Since you can define your own tag-names in HTML5, you can rename the `button` elements with the active class to `activebutton`. That way you can target them with the `:last-of-type` selector. This might be the closest to what you are trying here. You could get rid of the underlayer as well...
2. You could indicate the active element in it's parent. In this case the container, and target the nth child.
3. You could add an extra class to the last active element in your html
4. You could go the javascript route...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: start
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

button ,
buttona,
span{
  padding: 0 50px;
  border: 0;
  height: 32px;
  font-family: 'system-ui';
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

buttona,
span{
  background: teal;
  color: white;
}

button:after,
buttona:after,
span:after{
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  right: 0;
  width: 1px;
  top: 0;
}

buttona:first-of-type,
span:first-of-type{
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
}

buttona:last-of-type,
span:last-of-type{
  border-top-right-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}

buttona:last-of-type:after,
span:last-of-type:after{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <buttona>1</buttona>
  <buttona>2</buttona>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) I am using Angular, which means I would have to create custom components just for that --- 2) since it is dynamic, it means I would have to add the `:after` rules dynamically in the style sheet for every step change, which isn't that convenient --- 3) this is my actual solution (which is done with 4)) but I would have liked to be able to do it with CSS only ... I'll stick to this current solution for now I guess, thank you for your input on the matter ! (and more importantly, understanding the issue, not like the previous question ...)

Comment: @temp_user If you don't want Angular to try and parse your custom tags, you could just use any existing tag within that container. Why not use a span, and in your css style the ```.container span```

Comment: _“but I would have liked to be able to do it with CSS only”_ - why insist on that, when not even your underlying “pill” element actually does that to begin with? `width: calc(40% - 12px);` would need modifying somehow anyway, if you want it to cover a different number of active steps …

Comment: @04FS this is a [mcve], not my actual implementation. It doesn't contain Angular either, in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: @JasperZelf the combination of #3 & #4 solution seems easier than your comment with the span I have to say (and I'm already using it), implementing your comment would simply mean more complexity to my code