# How to select the last div based on attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this html code:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    [other divs]
    <div data-day="1">content</div>
    [other divs with data-day attribute]
    <div data-day="random">content</div>
    [other divs]
</div>
```

I wanna select the last element in the mydiv that has data-day attribute. How can I do this?

```
#mydiv div[data-day]:last-child
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected, but I wanted to know if I can use only CSS, no JS or unique class/id. It would be nice if there were a :last selector, like in JQuery.

Comment: If you know the value of data-day, then #mydiv[data-day="random"];else [data-day]:last-child{css;} work for css3 browsers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no *real* css-only solution to your question. With Javascript you could do this, I guess.

- `last-child` doesn't work, because it only works for the last element of its parent.
  In your case: Only if it was the last element with no other element following it.
- `last-of-type` doesn't work, because it only selects by *types*, not attributes or classes.

**Workaround:**

Add a class to the last element with a certain attribute by hand:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div></div>
    <div data-day="1">content</div>
    <div></div>
    <div data-day="random" class="last-data-day">content</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done a quick google search and found the following links useful:

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/)

[Stack Overflow (User with same issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i)

**The answer is:**

`:last-child` only works when the element in question is the last child of the container, not the last of a specific type of element. For that, you want `:last-of-type`

http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/3/

Comment: `:last-of-type` won't work here because they're all of the same type (divs).

Comment: ^ i concur.  It appears the `type` is limited only to `element` types specifically and not sub-selectors.  A quick fork of that fiddle shows this very easily http://jsfiddle.net/qnQsL/

Comment: @Deryck Exactly. `last-of-type` only works for _types_, not classes, attributes etc.