# CSS - Basic specificity

Tags: css

I have an HTML table with numerous columns. I want to set `text-align: center` on all columns except one.

I've heard that both using !important and unnecessary nesting is frowned upon. What is the "best" way to achieve this?

1. Using `!important`:

```
#my-table td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.my-table-special-td {
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

1. Unnecessary nesting:

```
#my-table td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#my-table .my-table-special-td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Or some other method?

By "best" I mean:
* Conformance to CSS best practices
* Good performance

Comment: What do you mean with _Unnecessary nesting_?

Comment: @user3117610 maybe you can get here some idea's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i

Comment: You shouldn't use `!important` indeed, at least not "by design", you should use it only to fix something when the change required would be too big without using it. The "class" solution seems a good one (and is no "unnecessary nesting") but if you know for sure the index of the column you could also use `nth-child`.

Comment: Yes I can add classes. By unnecessary nesting I mean that the "my-table" specifier before "my-table-special-td" is redundant.

Comment: there is no need, to worry about redundancy in a css file, you better take care that your code stays readable, which is not that easy with nested elements)

Comment: Redundancy = larger file size. Both Google and FF warn that nesting selectors is harmful for performance. I'm just trying to get in the right mindset regarding such problems before doing throw-away work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `!important`, unless you do not have any other choice.

```
#my-table td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

td#my-table-special-td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

you do not have to do any nesting. just use `id` istead of `class` and add tag name in front of it as you can see in the above code.

here is an example of it [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwboetsj/1/)

Comment: I don't think this works. ".my-table-special-td" is less specific than the "#my-table td" rule, so it remains centered.

Answer (score 1):

For performance wise, use inline styling for all your css. This is the technique used in google mail (Gmail) and I think Yahoo! mail as well. So if it's speed you want. Use inline style for everything. Honestly I wouldn't go that route because it does not offer clean and re-usable code.

So I would go with the cleanest solution which is giving the element a class name and avoid using !important. It is definitely frowned upon and it does not have to be used to be honest. The table will respect your class name on your table element. This offers a more clean CSS in the end that works on all browsers. If you are overriding classes in General, it means you might want to rethink the architecture of your CSS. I do not mean you are doing it the wrong way, but we are talking about the best way of doing things aren't we? :)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `!important` for "overriding" classes. Things like:

```
.center {text-align:center !important}
.right {text-align:right !important}
```

And so on - if I specify `class="right"` on an element, it's because I specifically want it right-aligned and `!important` helps reflect that.

However in more general cases, you should avoid `!important` - mostly because once you've used `!important`, there's no way to override it any more!

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
.tableAll td{
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
```

and you just want to center only so why define class. Inline style will work in this case and will override matching style of `.tableAll`.

```
<table class="tableAll">
 <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td >other all</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I don't recommentd using `!important`.

Comment: I don't like the idea of mixing inline CSS, I think that's a nono of best practices.

Comment: @user3117610 Inline styles are good if you it is not going too long and mess with tags. If it is `.class` is best practice. In your case there is one and you are not writing it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both solutions are fine using `!important` and nesting,

You should not use `!important` too often, because once it spreads and you use  it over and over again, you will be back at the beginning (difficulty in specifying elements specific to override other styles, applied),
 but in that particular case you are fine since  the `!important` rule only affects 1 element.

Nesting also works good, as long as you use it for special cases and not for every single element, because once you do so, your code will be unreadable and you will have a very hard time in improving and re factoring.

Answer (score 0):

```
#my-table td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#my-table td.my-special-td {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Arguably you don't need the `#my-table` selector as you stated you wanted to **all** `td` elements to be aligned to the center.

A more reuseable approach would be to remove the `id` and just have:

```
td { text-align:center; }
td.left-align { text-align:left;}
td.right-align {text-align:right;}
```

Then you can apply the alignment to any `td` anywhere, as well as override if you need to by adding an `id` to the table later on.

Comment: Since there's more than 1 table on my site, I do need the #my-table specifier. However, since none of the other tables have a my-table-special-td, specifying "#my-table" in conjunction with that seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend to use `!important` . In your case using `text-align: center` you can center the text and if you want for any column text should be `left-align` you could make a particular class for that `column` or better use some advance level CSS3.

In this example I want to change the `Last Column` of `Last row` and want to apply class.

I can do this by adding this style.

```
table tr:last-child td:nth-child(5) {background:red;}
```

Or better check this example. http://jsbin.com/mizotofe/1/