# CSS lists and preudoclasses. Only CSS solution required

Tags: html, css

How have can I set styles for the last list element of the nested list. I want these styles to be applied only to elements with the class "match".

Here is the code example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="match">x1 match</li>
            <li class="match">y1 match</li>
            <li>z1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>x2 match</li>
            <li class="match">y2 match</li>
            <li>z2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="match">x3 match</li>
            <li class="match">y3 match</li>
            <li class="match">y3 match</li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li ul li:last-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RYz6e/1/

To be specific in this example I want next items to be selected:

- y1 match
- y2 match
- y3 match

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `last-of-class` selector.

Comment: More info at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i

Comment: There are 2 lines with "y3" in them. Typo?

Comment: I don't want to add extra class. Is there a pure CSS solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. In Selectors Level 4 there's `:nth-match()`, but it's not yet implemented in most (possibly any) browsers.

Comment: As @Paulie_D said the CSS selector you are looking for doesn't exist. Either you add a specific class to the elements either you will need JS to select your elements.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want.. http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/PjuUz/ please be more clear and elaborative

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RYz6e/7/
If more elements come, this won't work

Comment: 2 Marmik - No. I need only the last match per list

Comment: 2 Leo T Abraham: even !== last

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul li ul .match:nth-of-type(even)
{
    color: red;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RYz6e/7/)

This won't work if more elements come.

Comment: No, there is *no* 'pure solution...with CSS,' (was that a typo?) and if you're suggesting jQuery (why not plain JavaScript?) then at least offer that solution.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have found a solution. But it will not work if more elements come.

Answer (score -2):

try to like below using css3

```
ul li:last-child
    {
    color: red;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and `:last-child` is css 2.1, not 3.

Comment: tell clearly what you need exaclty

Comment: Had I asked the question, I would have.

Comment: "tell clearly what you need exaclty" - I listed elements to be selected in the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas: shall we use jquery for this solution?

Comment: Ask the OP, @And1; it's his decision not mine.

Answer (score -2):

Or you could use:

```
ul .match {
color: red;
}
```

For a shorter notation.