# Get last instance of class in element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to get the last instance of a `div` with a class of `one_third`. I have tried many different orders of the `:last-child` but I can not get them to work.

Here is the structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one_third">One</div>
    <div class="one_third">Two</div>
    <div class="one_third">Three</div> <-- remove the margin from this one
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I tried doing

```
.container:last-child .one_third { margin-right: 0; }
```

this removes the margin from ALL divs with that class not just the last one. How can I get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: You want to select the last div? use like this `.container>:last-child{color:red;}`.

Comment: @mbeckish thats fails on few conditions

Comment: @zachstames check my updated answer... it may be your best bet here I'm afraid.

Comment: Another approach is using `::after` pseudo-element to implement the clearfix hack and then simply select the last child of the container like so: http://jsbin.com/zebuy/1/edit This is used by TW Bootstrap and most of the CSS frameworks as well.

Comment: Yes, I also like @HashemQolami solution as well.  I think that's a cleaner clearfix hack than the div version anyway and it makes your markup... better.  :P

Comment: @KheemaPandey - Yes, I believe the consensus from that other post is that it can't be done.  If someone comes up with a solution, it should be posted on that earlier thread, and this post should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container .one_third:last-child {
}
```

Comment: Pseudo classes work on elements, not classes of elements.

Comment: @j08691 well that certainly doesn't sound correct.

Comment: thats because its not!

Comment: @wumm - Since the dawn of HTML

Comment: @j08691 http://jsfiddle.net/jz6nw3cf/  This jsfiddle says you're horribly wrong

Comment: @j08691 you're misinformed if you believe thats correct.

Comment: @nzifnab - You obvioulsy don't understand what you're doing. Tell me why the last one-third class isn't selected here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/csuhq3xf/. In your example, the class just happens to match the last child. Bad example.

Comment: Because it's not the  last child of it's parent.  `.one_fourth` is.

Comment: @nzifnab you are correct

Comment: @j08691 According to W3 `E:last-child` selects `an E element, last child of its parent`

Comment: @j08691 your example wouldn't work with element selectors either... unless the element you were selecting was the *last child of it's parent*

Comment: okay so thats the issue then because I have a clearfix div as the last element. I though it would ignore that and just look for the last one with that class not the last in the container

Comment: To all of you who don't know the spec, `:last-child` selects the last child element of a parent. Period. It has nothing to do with the class of the element.

Comment: @wumm - that's exactly my point.

Comment: so what if I want to place a constrain to find the last element with that class regardless of if its the last in the container? without js

Comment: Doesn't work. When I add a 4th element to the container div, with a different class, "Third time" is no longer green.

Comment: @j08691 but if you have it connected to a selector like `a:last-child` or `.my-class:last-child` then it only works *if the element with that class is the last child of it's parent*.  If you connect it to something it has everything to do with the what you've connected it to.

Comment: Im aware I was asking the question to find a way to do that

Comment: @zachstarnes - Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i?rq=1?

Comment: Watch out for using `last-of-type`, as it may not be fully supported:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type  IE < 9 doesn't like it which will be your main concern.

Comment: i tried `.container .one-third:last-of-type` and that did not work

Comment: Same, I can't get a fiddle to make that work either.

Comment: @zachstarnes - You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: yeah thats dumb i thought adding the class would just find the last element with that class instead css ignores that and just does nothing or removes it off of all of them. Stupid.

Comment: The `:last-of-type` selector allows you to target the last occurence of an element within its container. this means as soon a new `div` will be added with different class `:last-of-type` won't work. check this link. http://jsbin.com/fudicipevemo/1/edit

Comment: @j08691: I agree that your very first comment on this answer doesn't really make sense - I would simply say that simple selectors match independently of one another, or do not affect one another.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off manually adding a `last` class to your last div, and targetting that.  Barring that, you're gonna have to use JS to get the last element with a specific class which is less than ideal.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one_third">One</div>
    <div class="one_third">Two</div>
    <div class="one_third last">Three</div> <-- remove the margin from this one
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.container .one_third.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

`.last-child` doesn't work in your instance because that pseudo-selector will only select *the last child of it's parent*.  So it'll work if there are no other kinda of elements after your last `one_third` div, but it won't work if there are.

`last-of-type` has it's own set of oddities where it will select based on the element type, not just the class name - regardless of what selector you've used in the CSS.  See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YmMZZ/1/

Comment: Ummm.  Why is this getting a negative score?  Is something here incorrect?

Comment: Doesn't work.  When I add a 4th element to the container div, with a different class, "Third time" is no longer green.

Comment: As mentioned in the other thread, that's because it's no longer the last child of your parent.  You have in fact changed your question since this answer was made -- the answer was correct before your change.

Comment: So delete this answer since it is no longer pertinent?

Comment: @mbeckish Or I could update the answer ;)

Comment: @nzifnab You should include at least some detail of why `last-child` and `last-of-type` do not work in the answer, as the comments will likely be deleted (as they should be).

Comment: Fair enough, I'm on it.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.container .one_third:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2a50r86/)

Comment: may you care enough to explain how it DID work in the fiddle, for Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: I already did. Read my comment again.

Comment: No you didn't. There's nothing incorrect about the fiddle. Even when copied the code into a blank HTML file, it still works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good article on `:nth-last-child` [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-child/).

I would try:

```css
.container .one-third:nth-last-child(1) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Not a huge fan of this solution as it's brittle.  If you have the same markup in another location without the clear hack-fix, then it won't work for selecting that last element anymore :\  I think a better solution might be to use one of the better clear-fixes that have been made available as opposed to the div variation.

Comment: `:nth-last-child(1)` is equivalent to `:last-child` and thus will not work.