# CSS: how to apply styles to the last <td> of a CSS class (not the last <td> of <tr>)

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="column-text">column 1</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 2</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 3</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 4</td>
    <td>last column has no class</td>
</tr>
```

Note that the number of cells with class "column-text" is dynamic.

I have the following CSS:

```
tr td.column-text:last-child {
    color: red;
}
```

Note that this selector seems not working.

What is the right CSS selector for the last `<td>` with class "column-text"?

Thanks and regards.

**UPDATE 1**

Just wanted to share this, which is puzzling to me. The following is working!

```
tr td.column-text:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

But as said in the post, I hope to apply styles to the last cell with the given class.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is what I did to solve this problem after realizing there is no direct CSS solution based on the input from helping folks. When generating the dynamic html, I added a special class to the last `<td>` with "column-text" class.

Thanks to all folks who rushed to help!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298062/2780033

Comment: Deryck, thanks for the link! I am not sure whether that answer is the answer. tr td.column-text:last-child {color: red;} does not apply to the last <td> (without "column-text" class) based on my tests. However, tr td.column-text:first-child {color: red;} works for the first <td>

Comment: There is no pure-CSS solution simply because the pseudo class selector does not apply to classes in a combinatorial way, not as intuitively as we thought. `.class:last-child` selects the last occurring element that has the class, not the last occurring element *of* the class. We are yet to have the `:last-of-class` selector, so JS is the only way.

Comment: Terry, could you please expand a little on ".class:last-child selects the last occurring element that has the class, not the last occurring element of the class."? I dont fully get it. Thanks!!

Comment: `last-child` selects the last child.  When you add the class selector it acts as a filter.  If the last child happens to have that class it is selected.  If not, then nothing is selected.

Comment: billynoah, thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: It would be great if you write your solution as an answer and accept it so that no one else finds this question looking for unanswered questions; and it would be easier for those with similar questions to find your answer.

Comment: Kamran, I just did that. Will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As folks here indicated, there is no pure-CSS solution for this. What I did is to simply add a new class ("last-column") to the last  with the given class. Something like the following:

```
<tr>
    <td class="column-text">column 1</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 2</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 3</td>
    <td class="column-text last-column">column 4</td>
    <td>last column has no class</td>
</tr>
```

The above html is generated dynamically and I am able to know which one is the last td with "column-text". I feel this way is better than using Javascript.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="column-text">column 1</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 2</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 3</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 4</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 5</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 6</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 7</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 8</td>
    <td class="column-text">column 9</td>
    <td>last column has no class</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr td:nth-last-child(2){
   color:red;
}
```

**This will expect there to be exactly only one `td` sibling at the end without the class `column-text`.**

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/jawv3p4g/)

Comment: Prashant, thanks for chiming in! Your answer seems not working.

Comment: Prashant, your answer is not what I am looking for. Please read my question again. Thanks!

Comment: @curious1 See if this is what you wanted.

Comment: @curious1 I would expect Prashant's answer in its current form to always select the last td.column-text. Is the number of td elements without the class also variable, or does the tr always end with exactly one classless td?

Comment: @curious1 It will not select the last `column-text` element. It will expect there to be only once `td` sibbling after the last `column-text`. Other than that, I don't think there's more dynamic solution only using CSS3.

Comment: It's hard coded but allows `.column-text` to be dynamic.

Comment: Prashant, I added my answer based on suggestion from Kamran.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it with CSS.  Here's a jQuery solution if you're interested:

```
$('td.column-text').eq($('td.column-text').length-1).css({color:'red'});
```

Comment: billynoah, thanks for your input. I am hoping to have a CSS solution.

Comment: Yeah, I got that.  If it's possible I'd love to know as well but I don't think so..

Answer (score 2):

`last-of-type` may have worked but it doesn't work with class names. If you don't mind, you may use:

```
$("td.column-text").last().css("color", "red");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfKamran/0ybkLe8e/)

Comment: Kamran, thanks for your input! I am hoping to have a CSS solution.

Comment: same as my answer but `last()` is better.. forgot about that one :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking an answer something like this example. [See here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6jzxfdu7/)

[image]

Comment: Anthony, as said in the post, the number of <td> with class "column-text" is dynamic. It could be 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anthony, in my case. It is a table. All elements under <td> need to be the same tag. last-of-type is helpful in your html structure. Not working in my scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS solution

```
td.column-text:nth-last-child(2) {color: red;}
```