# :last-of-type not working correctly

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/w28b68bL/

Here is my fiddle, I am breaking my head on why is this not working? I want the last `.checked` element to be red color, and I can't understand what's happening.

Ok, after reading it a bit, i figured out that `:last-of-type` doesn't work on classes. So again, my question is, how can I do this? Trying to get pure CSS solution, not JS one. (As I think I can make it work with JS myself).

```css
 .checked {
   color: blue;
 }
 .checked:last-of-type {
   background: red;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="select-it-list">
  <li data-order="1" data-value="AX" class="checked" style="display: list-item;">
    <input type="checkbox">Åland Islands</li>
  <li data-order="4" data-value="AS" class="checked" style="display: list-item;">
    <input type="checkbox">American Samoa</li>
  <li data-order="0" data-value="AF">
    <input type="checkbox">Afghanistan</li>
  <li data-order="1" data-value="AX" class="checked-hidden" style="display: none;">
    <input type="checkbox">Åland Islands</li>
  <li data-order="2" data-value="AL">
    <input type="checkbox">Albania</li>
  <li data-order="3" data-value="DZ">
    <input type="checkbox">Algeria</li>
  <li data-order="4" data-value="AS" class="checked-hidden" style="display: none;">
    <input type="checkbox">American Samoa</li>
  <li data-order="5" data-value="AD" class="" style="display: list-item;">
    <input type="checkbox">Andorra</li>
  <li data-order="6" data-value="AO">
    <input type="checkbox">Angola</li>
  <li data-order="7" data-value="AI">
    <input type="checkbox">Anguilla</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also this: [CSS last-child selector: select last-element of specific class, not last child inside of parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i)

Comment: Well that doesn't really help, as I can't add `.last` since the list is dynamical. (Yes, I know I can do it with JS, but I was asking for a pure CSS, if possible)

Comment: How is the list generated? You could add a specific class to the last item in the backend loop...

Comment: @Zmuci : You can add a different class on the last li with .checked and change it's color. But in pure css, i don't think it's possible

Comment: Once you click on the `li` without the `.checked` class it get's the class and get's pushed up in the line of other `li` elements with `.checked` class by `data-order` attribute.

Comment: Yea, I did it with JS, guess there's no other way.

Comment: `var allChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.checked');`  then `var totalChecked = allChecked.length;` then `var lastChecked = allChecked[totalChecked - 1]`