# how select last child of element that class begins - using CSS3 or SCSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select the last-child element who class begins with a specific value. Let's suppose I have the next html structure elements:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test-1">this is test-1</div>
  <div class="test-2">this is test-2</div>
  <div class="test-3">this is test-3</div>
  <div class="test-4">this is test-4</div>
  <div class="another-test">this is the another test</div>
</div>
```

So, I want to select the **div** with **class="test-4"**. I'm using the next SCSS code but it doesn't work.

```css
div.wrapper div[class^="test"]:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the :last selector and not the :last-child selector

Comment: Sorry, but there's currently no kind of "parameterized" `last-of-type` selector.

Comment: An even closer duplicate for this question is [CSS last-child selector: select last-element of specific class, not last child inside of parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7298057/5743988)

Comment: You might be able to get your desired result though with `:nth-last-child(2)`