# CSS Select last class before different class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Sorry for a bad title, didn't really know how to describe better. Page looks like this

*note: data-ids are random and i don't know them beforehand.*

```
<main>
    <h2 class="title">title1</h2>
    <div id="1-3" class="content" data-id="1"></div>
    <div id="1-2" class="content" data-id="1"></div>
    <div id="1-1" class="content" data-id="1"></div>

    <h2 class="title">title2</h2>
    <div id="2-11" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
    <div id="2-10" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
    <div id="2-9" class="content" data-id="2"></div>

    <h2 class="title">title3</h2>
    <div id="3-18" class="content" data-id="3"></div>
    <div id="3-17" class="content" data-id="3"></div>
    <div id="3-16" class="content" data-id="3"></div>
</main>
```

is there any way to hide all but last content divs after each h2 in pure CSS? I can't target them with id or data-id individually. is there any way to select all the elements with the same unspecified attribute? so all data-id="same" are selected and then I can unhide the nth-last-child(1)? I doubt there is something like this. Is there any way to accomplish this with just CSS?

I'm currently hiding every .content if the next sibling isn't .content with js but want to know if it's possible with CSS.

Comment: So you want to hide all but one div with content class after title3 right?

Comment: What exactly you want to select and what not?

Comment: @Oriol I want to show div id 1-1, 2-9 and 3-16. and want to hide other content divs.

Comment: In a distant future, maybe `.content:not(:has( + .content))` will work

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i#comment45175206_7298062

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible without any scripting..you need to use javascript or Jquery

Comment: Yeah as I said I'm currently doing this with js, was just wondering if I could get by without it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is possible. if you always have an `h2` followed by 2 hidden `divs` followed by a visible `div`, you can use the selector: `main:nth-child(4n-1), main:nth-child(4n-2)` to hide the hidden `divs`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to suggest putting each block of

```
<h2 class="title">title2</h2>
<div id="2-11" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
<div id="2-10" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
<div id="2-9" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
```

inside a `<section>`, like this:

```
<section>
<h2 class="title">title2</h2>
<div id="2-11" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
<div id="2-10" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
<div id="2-9" class="content" data-id="2"></div>
</section>
```

Then you can...

```css
div {
display: none;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

section:nth-of-type(1) div {
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

section:nth-of-type(2) div {
background-color: rgb(0,127,0);
}

section:nth-of-type(3) div {
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

section div:last-of-type {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>
    <h2 class="title">Title 1</h2>
    <div id="1-3" class="content" data-id="1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="1-2" class="content" data-id="1">Div 2</div>
    <div id="1-1" class="content" data-id="1">Div 3</div>
    </section>

    <section>
    <h2 class="title">Title 2</h2>
    <div id="2-11" class="content" data-id="2">Div 1</div>
    <div id="2-10" class="content" data-id="2">Div 2</div>
    <div id="2-9" class="content" data-id="2">Div 3</div>
    </section>

    <section>
    <h2 class="title">Title 3</h2>
    <div id="3-18" class="content" data-id="3">Div 1</div>
    <div id="3-17" class="content" data-id="3">Div 2</div>
    <div id="3-16" class="content" data-id="3">Div 3</div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Yeah If I could modify html than it would be trivial, but seems like what I was asking is impossible to do with css currently. Anyway I don't need it anymore so no big deal.

Comment: Hmm. You didn't mention that you couldn't modify html. That's not a normal situation. And, even then, depending on other factors, hiding all divs but the last one after each `h2` is absolutely possible. For instance, if you always have an `h2` followed by 2 hidden `divs` followed by a visible `div`, you can use the selector: `main:nth-child(4n-1), main:nth-child(4n-2)` to hide the hidden `divs`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mention html because I asked if it could be done in pure css. divs numbers after h2 vary, so that method wouldn't work. It's no longer a problem though, I left it working with javascript, as it couldn't be done with css. Thanks for your help.