# CSS selector with nth-child works but not last-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div`, which contains 3 child `divs`.

I have a selector `.parent-div .child-div:nth-child(1)` which selects the first child div.

And `.parent-div .child-div:nth-child(3)` selects the last child div.

But, `.parent-div .child-div:last-child` selects nothing.

Any clues on what could be the issue? Does it have anything to do with `float` or `absolute` positioning?

Incidentally, I made the divs sortable using JQuery UI, which might have added some additional classes.

**Edit:**
The .parent-div has 3 .childA-div's and one .child-clear div. So, the last .childA-div is not considered as a last-child because the real last child is of a different class.

I used nth-last-child(2) as suggested below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS last-child selector: select last-element of specific class, not last child inside of parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i)

Comment: Do you need that `.child-clear` element? If it's legacy code, probably yes but you can use `:after` pesudo or the (micro-)[clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) (IE8+ and IE6+ with zoom: 1 but who cares about IE6-7 nowadays)

Comment: @FelipeAls I didn't realize that that was the problem earlier. As for the clear fix, I'll ook into the other options. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.child-div:nth-last-child(1) { }`

The `:nth-last-child(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent, counting from the last child.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I used nth-last-child(2). It happens that there is another child div, which is not of class .child-div. It is a float clear div.