# CSS :last-child Selector doesn't work

Tags: css, select, css-selectors

I use :last-child Selector but It's doesn't work.
Example:

```
.last {background:blue;border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;}

.last:last-child {background:red;border-bottom:0px solid #cccccc;}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/)

Thanks every one's answer.

But I haver an other Question.
[jsfiddle example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/2/)

```css
.big_box {
  background:#eeeeee;
  height:500px;
}

.last {
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
background: yellow;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.last:last-child {
    background: red;
     border-bottom: 0px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="big_box">
  <div class="other">the other paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The first paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The second paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The third paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The fourth paragraph.</div>
  <div class="other">the other paragraph.</div>
  <div class="other">the other paragraph.</div>
  <div class="other">the other paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is simply a jsfiddle quirk. Wrap your divs in a parent div and it works fine.

Comment: The other question  : https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/2/

Comment: Here there is a post with what you are trying to get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i  I think this post is duplicated

Comment: @lucianov88 Thank you, but he used different type (div and article).

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is use a wrapper element. Check it out when you use one.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/1/)

```
<div>
  <div class="last">The first paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The second paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The third paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The fourth paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

.

```
.last {
background: yellow;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.last:last-child {
    background: red;
     border-bottom: 0px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I have other question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/2/   In this example, It's doesn't work. But I don't know why...

Comment: AFAIK that doesn't work because of the complex way CSS parsers work. Unfortunately there's no way around that without using JS.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `last-child` does indeed reference the child element. But `.last` was already a child. It was a child of the `body` element.

Comment: If it was just a bug in jsFiddle, then it would work when on its own page. That's not the case.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. Doesn't work in Stack Snippet either. I removed that section from my comment.

Comment: Just keep in mind that your answer is premised on the idea that the divs are not already children in the HTML structure. They are, however. That's why your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

***Answer for Q1:(befor updated your post)***

> `<div class="last">The fourth paragraph.</div>` is one before the last no last because In Fiddle your code is like(Use Dev Tools):

```
<body>
  <div class="last">The first paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The second paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The third paragraph.</div>
  <div class="last">The fourth paragraph.</div>
  <script>...</script>
</body>
```

so, last child is `<script>` no `<div class="last">The fourth paragraph.</div>`.

for fix i use of:

```
.last:nth-last-child(2) {
    background: red;
     border-bottom: 0px solid #cccccc;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/5/)

also,you can use of `div:last-of-type` :

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/7/)

Thankyou @Michael_B.

***Answer for Q2:(after updated your post):***

you must use of `.last:nth-child(5) {` :

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/8/)

Comment: Brilliant! This is the answer. (And it was staring me in the face with Dev Tools open on my screen! smh) .. Nice work!

Comment: @Michael_B , you are welcome!

Comment: And the script element is last child in stack snippet also.

Comment: `div:last-of-type` / `.last:last-of-type` would also work. https://jsfiddle.net/6dpodkkx/7/

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```css
.last{
  background:yellow;
  border-bottom:0px solid #cccccc;
}

.last div:last-child{
  background:red;
  border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="last">
  <div>The first paragraph.</div>
  <div>The second paragraph.</div>
  <div>The third paragraph.</div>
  <div>The fourth paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this is *not* the same thing. In the original example each row had its own border.

Comment: The `last` class name makes no sense in this context.