# Use last-child on angular selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How do I get the last-child CSS selector to work on an angular component selector? I want to add styles to the last component item with a particular class.

My HTML:

```
<component-name class="abc"></component-name>
<component-name class="abc"></component-name>
<component-name class="abc"></component-name>
<component-name class="efg"></component-name>
<component-name class="efg"></component-name>
```

In the case above, I would like to style the last .abc item. So my CSS:

```
component-name.abc:last-child {
 // some styles
}
```

This doesn't work. Neither does this:

```
component-name.abc:last-of-type {
    // some styles
}
```

How do I select the last-child in this case?

Comment: This should work. But in the parent component, not the children components. Where did you try to select the last child ?

Comment: CSS doesn't have a 'last-of-class' selector..

Comment: @trichetriche when i do `component-name: last-of-type` it works on the last element (not what i want, just checking), but when I do `component-name.abc:last-child` or `component-name.abc:last-of-type` it doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with @sol, why don't u use the :nth-of-type selector?

Comment: @sol do you mean, you can't select the last-child by class on css?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298062/5561605

Comment: ..and this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: I don't think it's possible. People look how to achieve a `:nth-of-class` or `:last-of-class` selector, but it seems that it is just not possible. See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector/5546296#5546296

Comment: Typical deficiency of the :last-child selector.

Answer (score 0):

Is the css code you posted within the `component-name.css`-file? If that's the case move it to the parent component style sheet or `style.css`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery `last()`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('component-name.abc').last().css( "background-color", "red" )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<component-name class="abc">abc</component-name>
<component-name class="abc">abc</component-name>
<component-name class="abc">abc</component-name>
<component-name class="efg">efg</component-name>
<component-name class="efg">efg</component-name>
```

Reference Link:

- [last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)

Answer (score -3):

You could try the nth-of-type selector.

I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34vwp9xd/

```
.abc:nth-of-type(3) {
  background:red;
}
```

But it's less than ideal because you have to know the index of the class you want to style, I think your going to need to use JS to solve this by adding a `last` class to the last element of class abc

Comment: Why the downvote? :last-child wont work here, has to be :last-of-type

Comment: `last-of-type` will select the last `<component-name>`. Since it doesn't have the `.abc` class, it won't select anything. Try it in a Codepen or something (I did), it doesn't work. Sorry, downvoted as well :)

Comment: I downvoted for same reason, sorry -- see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298062/5561605

Comment: My bad, I was sure i have done something like this in the past but that must of been on an actual element whoops