# Row gap is filling background color with first column

Tags: html, css

I have started learning CSS Grid today and I have a doubt.
When using `gap` property the second row is displaying the gaps perfectly but first row's gap are filled with the first column background color. I don't understand why.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: coral;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: darksalmon;
}
div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: deeppink;
}
div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />

    <style>
      .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
        grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
        gap: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT :**
[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Because `div:nth-child(6)`<sup>1</sup> is also applying to your container element since it's the 6th child considering the other elements inside the body.

[image]

Make your selector more specific and target only the div inside `.container` to avoid such issue:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: coral;
}
.container > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: darksalmon;
}
.container > div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: deeppink;
}
.container > div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />

    <style>
      .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
        grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
        gap: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that it won't behave the same everywhere. Here in the snippet `:nth-child(6)` is applying but using a different tool another selector may apply depending on how the elements are generated.

<sup>1</sup>In your output the `nth-child(1)` is applying because you are probably testing locally where the code won't change and your container will remain the first child.

Related: [How can I select the first or the last child with CSS correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48632929/8620333)