# Not getting correct output by :not() pseudo class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
div:not(.awesome) {
  color: red;
}

 :not(div) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Selected for 1st</div>
<div class="awesome">Not selected</div>
<section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
<section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
```

Now browser shows the first line of html in red color and remaining three lines are in blue color. But I think the second line should not be colored blue because it has class value "awesome" and it is  element. So it is against both rules I wrote in my css.Therefor,it should be not styled.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Add border to notice that `:not(div)` is also selecting `body` and `html` element. your second element is not being selected but is **inherting** the color from body.

You can clearly notice there is no border around the second `div`:

```css
div:not(.awesome) {
  color: red;
}

 :not(div) {
  color: blue;
  border:1px solid
}
```

```html
<div>Selected for 1st</div>
<div class="awesome">Not selected</div>
<section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
<section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
```

Define a color to body to have another result:

```css
div:not(.awesome) {
  color: red;
}

 :not(div) {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid
}

body {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div>Selected for 1st</div>
<div class="awesome">Not selected</div>
<section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
<section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
```

Better consider a wrapper when applying a selector to make sure the scope of your selection is well defined and you don't select unwanted elements. You may use the `body` element but it's not recommended because even [the `body` can give you some surprise.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632960/8620333)

```css
.container div:not(.awesome) {
  color: red;
}

.container :not(div) {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Selected for 1st</div>
  <div class="awesome">Not selected</div>
  <section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
  <section>This is selected for 2nd</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Good explanation. To work around this he can use the `body :not(div)` selector