# how to seleect the last sibling in a group using only css?

Tags: css

I have a list of items related to each other

```
<dl>
    <dd data-grupo="1">1. Tomatoes</dd>
    <dd data-grupo="1">2. Cucumbers</dd>
    <dd data-grupo="1">3. Mushrooms</dd>
    <dd data-grupo="2">4. Apples</dd>
    <dd data-grupo="2">5. Mangos</dd>
    <dd data-grupo="2">6. Pears</dd>
    <dd data-grupo="2">7. Oranges</dd>
</dl>
```

How can I select the first and last sibling in the group `data-grupo="1"` and `data-grupo="2"` to make them red and blue? Using only css

I've tried

```
dl dd[data-grupo="1"]:first-child,
dl dd[data-grupo="1"]:last-child{

  background: red;

}


dl dd[data-grupo="2"]:nth-child(1),
dl dd[data-grupo="2"]:nth-child(-1){
  background: blue;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select the last element with a specific class, not last child inside of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/how-can-i-select-the-last-element-with-a-specific-class-not-last-child-inside-o)

Answer (score 0):

ou'll notice that one of what you want actually seems to work:

```css
dl dd[data-grupo="1"]:first-child,
dl dd[data-grupo="1"]:last-child{

  background: red;

}
dl dd[data-grupo="2"]:nth-child(1),
dl dd[data-grupo="2"]:nth-child(-1){
  background: blue;

}
```

```html
    <dl>
        <dd data-grupo="1">1. Tomatoes</dd>
        <dd data-grupo="1">2. Cucumbers</dd>
        <dd data-grupo="1">3. Mushrooms</dd>
        <dd data-grupo="2">4. Apples</dd>
        <dd data-grupo="2">5. Mangos</dd>
        <dd data-grupo="2">6. Pears</dd>
        <dd data-grupo="2">7. Oranges</dd>
    </dl>
```

The problem is your understand of how selectors work.  Selectors are an all or nothing.

```
dl dd[data-grupo="1"]:first-child
```

This doesn't mean give me the first child of elements in the selector `dd[data-grupo="1"]`.

It means, turn red only the target element is in a `dl` is a `dd[data-grupo="1"]` AND is `:first-child` (is the first child).

That's why the it works for the `:first-child` and not the `:last-child` because the last child of `dl` is a `<dd data-grupo="2">` not `dd[data-grupo="1"]`.