# Target last element with a specific class

Tags: css, sass

I have following markup.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.progress {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.progress .progress-item {
  background-color: grey;
}

.progress .progress-item.done {
  background-color: blue;
}

.progress > div.done:last-of-type,
.progress > .done:last-child,
.progress .done:last-of-type,
.progress div:last-of-type {
  background-color: red !important;
  border: 4px green solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-item done">1</div>
  <div class="progress-item done">2</div>
  <div class="progress-item done">3</div>
  <div class="progress-item">4</div>
  <div class="progress-item">5</div>
  <div class="progress-item">6</div>
  <p >7</p>
  <p class="progress-item">8</p>
</div>
```

I want to apply the red background and border styles to 3rd div. `.progress div:last-of-type` does seem to work (applied on last 6th div), but `.progress .done:last-of-type` is not working. I have added all queries that I have tried but didn't work.

Comment: Note that: "`.item:last-of-type` selects the last of every type *if that last element also has the item class*," not necessarily the last element with that class. [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) (my emphasis).

Comment: You might find this answer helpful: [How can I select the last element with a specific class, not last child inside of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75200868/924299)

Comment: The above premise is the reason. However if it is possible to update your html. may be  this might help?https://codepen.io/mandy8055/pen/KKJaKbo?editors=1000