# CSS: :last-child on list item

Tags: css, html-lists, css-selectors

If a ul has li items with multiple classes, is it possible to get the last item of a specific class using :last-child?

For example, consider following:

```
<ul class="test">
    <li class="one">
    <li class="one">
    <li class="one">
    <li class="two">
    <li class="two">
</ul>
```

I want to add some style to the last li having class "one" (ie. third in the list).

I tried following and it does not work.

```
ul.test li.one:last-child
```

Comment: I think you haven't searched for it that much? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css

Comment: Same question but (some) different answers. There is value in repetition!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's not possible [*yet*](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#nth-match).

- [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:last-child) selects the last child, regardless of the tag name, etc.
- The possible alternative, [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:last-of-type) selects the last occurrence of a **tag**. It ignores the class name, etc.

Your only option is to add a specific class name to that element, or use JavaScript to add this class name.

Comment: Thanks but how the :last-of-type will work in above html example?

Comment: @user1355300 It won't work as expected. In your example, there's only one type of child, namely `<li>`. So, `:last-child` and `:last-of-type` selects the same element (the 5th `<li>`). See http://jsfiddle.net/vEphZ/

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for future viewers, I think Rob W got the answer right but forgot to put it wholly. This: `ul.test > li:last-of-type` should work to select only the last item in the test list

Answer (score 5):

Instead of giving class for each li, you can go for nth child where you can assign the style by li number.

If you want to give the separate css for your 3rd li then you need to write

```
li:nth-child(3) {
    color: green;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/HyAhL/2/

**Jquery code:**

```
var n = $('.one').length;
$('.one').eq(n-1).css('color', 'red');
```