# How to remove border-bottom of last div in a group - CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the border bottom of last div "footer_column"? Here is my HTML -

```
<div id="footer_wrapper"> <!-- footer_wrapper starts here -->
    <div id="footer"> <!-- footer starts here -->
    <div class="footer_column">
        <h4>Digital Strategy</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_column">
        <h4>Search</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google AdWords</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bing Ads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Remarketing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_column">
        <h4>Social</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook Ads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Youtube Ads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_column">
        <h4>Conversion</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Landing Page Creation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A/B Testing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_column">
        <h4>Contact Us</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>

        <div id="copyright">
            <p>&copy; 2014.</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- footer ends here -->
</div> <!-- footer_wrapper ends here -->
```

This is CSS -

```
/* footer */
.footer_column
{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #8f8f8f;
}

.footer_column:last-child
{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

But it's not working. The last div "footer_column" still have border bottom. I know I can remove it by using first-child and border-top but I don't want to do that. I only want to do it with border-bottom and last-child. Please help me on this.

Comment: The element you want to target is not actually the *last-child* of its parent. The last child would be `copyright`.

Comment: but i want to target last element of class .footer_column in the group. how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep is simple stupid, either:

1. Add another class, .footer-last-child and remove the border:

   **.footer-last-child { border-bottom:none;}**

and classify the last child with it as a second class:

```
<div class="footer_column footer-last-child">
```

OR -

2. Add an ID to this item, and remove the border: **#last-child{border-bottom:none;}**

while your HTML would be

```
<div class="footer_column" id="last-child">
```

Answer (score 2):

@LcSalazar is right, `last-child` literally means the last child in an element - not the last one of the set of `.footer_columns`, as you seem to be expecting. So your `last-child` rule will only be applied if there are no other elements after it.

One solution would be to wrap all of those `.footer_columns` in a container like so:

```
<div id="footer_wrapper"> <!-- footer_wrapper starts here -->
    <div id="footer"> <!-- footer starts here -->
    <div class="footer_column_container">
        <div class="footer_column">
            <h4>Digital Strategy</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column">
            <h4>Search</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Google AdWords</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bing Ads</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Remarketing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column">
            <h4>Social</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook Ads</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Youtube Ads</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column">
            <h4>Conversion</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Landing Page Creation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A/B Testing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column">
            <h4>Contact Us</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>

        <div id="copyright">
            <p>&copy; 2014. All Rights Reserved. eCLICKS New Zealand - eCLICKS United Arab Emirates.</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- footer ends here -->
</div> <!-- footer_wrapper ends here -->
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the element you want to target is not actually the last-child of its parent. The last child in this case would be the `copyright` div.

Also, there's no "last of the class" selector. ([CSS: How to say .class:last-of-type [classes, not elements!]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements))

Perhaps you can target the specific child nth:

```
.footer_column:nth-child(5) {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Though it would require the divs count to be constant.

Comment: I think he was referring to the last footer_column div and not to the copyright one

Comment: @PalDev Yes, of course. That's what I'm explaining.

Comment: ah ye :-) missed the begining

Answer (score 1):

Your `footer_column` DIV is not the last child. Your `copyright` DIV is the last child.

Try moving the `copyright` and `clr` DIV out of the `footer` DIV.

There is currently no CSS selector to choose the last element with a particular class within a container.