# CSS Pseudo Class Selection not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ol>
    <li><a id="a" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="b" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="c" href="#">This one</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>Not this</span></li>
</ol>
```

I want to select #c via CSS. I have tried:

```
ol > li:not(.active):last-child > a {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

As I understand it li:not(.active) selects all the li elements but the one with class .active.

On this selection I use :last-child to get the last of these li elements. But this wont work. What's wrong? Is it possible what I'm trying to achieve?

Thank you very much :)

PS: The list length is dynamic and **the elements does not have any id that could be used for CSS selection** (I just used some in the example to clarify which element I want to select) ;)

Comment: When class `active` will be on, let's say, #b, which one you want to target? `#a` (last before), or `#d` (last without .active)? Don't forget that support of :last-child is IE9+

Comment: Well, the active class will always be on the last element. Browser support is not an issue for me :)

Comment: Do u want to access 2nd last child always??

Comment: @Dimple: Yeah, kind of... :)

Comment: @Fidel90 If that's your need, check out my answer with the second snippet!

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I did and accepted ;) Thank you very much for the effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pseudo code that you wrote **works**! There's no `last-child` of `<li>` with no `active` class. So your code fails any time! Check with another one in which, the last `<li>` doesn't have an `active`.

Or you need to use `last-of-type`. Check the fiddle:

```css
ol > li:not(.active):last-child > a {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

ol > li:not(.active):last-of-type > a {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><a id="a" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="b" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="c" href="#">This one</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>Not this</span></li>
</ol>

<ol>
    <li><a id="a" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="b" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>Not this</span></li>
    <li><a id="c" href="#">This one</a></li>
</ol>
```

One thing to note is, `last-of-type` doesn't consider `:not()`. Check [CSS: How to say .class:last-of-type [classes, not elements!]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements)! You might need to use JavaScript or jQuery for this.

**Partial Solution**

If you know that the `Not this` always occurs in the last, you can use `nth-last-child(2)`:

```css
ol > li:not(.active):nth-last-child(2) > a {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><a id="a" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="b" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="c" href="#">This one</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>Not this</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Your partial solution did it for me! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Fidel90 Gald that it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following CSS:

```css
ol > li:not(.active):nth-last-child(1) > a,
 ol > li:not(.active):nth-last-child(2) > a {
   border: 1px solid green;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a id="a" href="#">Not this</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="b" href="#">Not this</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="c" href="#">This one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a id="d" href="#">Not this</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li><a id="e" href="#">Not this</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="f" href="#">Not this</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a id="g" href="#">Not this</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="h" href="#">This one</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

This code would work only if the last two can't have the active class at the same time. If they, at some point, both have the active class, this css would also fail.

Comment: @Fidel90 If this fixed your problem and the other answers didn't, change the solution to this answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check  this out: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

If you want to select only second last child then you can try:

```css
ol li:nth-last-child(2) a{
border:1px solid green
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><a id="a" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="b" href="#">Not this</a></li>
    <li><a id="c" href="#">This one</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>Not this</span></li>
</ol>
```