# Get last instance of a class under a parent with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to select the `nth-child` or `last-child` of a specific type of class among the same elements?

ie

if I use `.small:last-child` or `ul .small:last-child` that property will only affect the very last element of the second list. Is there a selector that I can use to select the last instance of `small` in each list?

```
<ul>
    <li class="small">List Item</li>
    <li class="small">List Item</li>
    <li class="medium">List Item</li>
    <li class="large">List Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="medium">List Item</li>
    <li class="large">List Item</li>
    <li class="small">List Item</li>
    <li class="small">List Item</li>
</ul>
```

Please see fiddle CSS Line 72 for reference

http://jsfiddle.net/j7wq12v2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i it is not supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:last-child` only works when the element in question is the last child of the container, not the last of a specific type of element. We could have used `last-of-type`

Unfortunately finding the last `.class` is not possible with `last-of-type`.

We need to use javascript in order to achieve the result.

Comment: I tried that, and it still does not apply the property. Let me try and reproduce with a fiddle.

Comment: Ok, so I guess it is not possible. I will just manually add a "last" class to counter the issue - it's not a big deal hardcoding this for 6 elements

Comment: I think that is all you can do

Answer (score 2):

Edit: actually, it may not be possible to use the `last-of-type` psuedo selector on classes, [check this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements).