# How to select the last rowspan in a table?

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-table

I have a table with some `<td>`s, and a couple of them have `rowspan` attribute. I'm trying to select the very last one in the table, neither `last-child` nor `last-of-type` works.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p2cjwvj5/

```
<table class='myTable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='3'>HEADER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='3'>HEADER2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
.myTable [rowspan]:last-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

I'm trying to to select the cell that contains "HEADER2".

Is this possible? I know I can work around it by tagging the last `rowspan` with another class, just wonder if there is a cleaner method. Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: How to say .class:last-of-type \[classes, not elements!\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements)

Comment: Still not possible to achieve without editing the html. But since I'm generating the table in the backend in groups, I can easily add in the ``tbody`` tag. Therefore the solution provided by Pangloss below is an acceptable solution that's still cleaner than the workaround I would have done. Thanks everyone!

Comment: why you delete? I give you the answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each group of `<tr>`s into a `<tbody>`, then select the last `tbody` by either using `:last-of-type` or `:last-child` would be fine.

```css
.myTable tbody:last-of-type td[rowspan] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class='myTable' border='1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='3'>HEADER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan='3'>HEADER2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>something2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>something2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add more `<tbody>`s, you could always just put a class on the last `rowspan`-ed table cell, like:

```css
.myTable .lastRowspannedCell {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class='myTable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='3'>HEADER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='3' class='lastRowspannedCell'>HEADER2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>something2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know the structure of your back-end code, so that's assuming you can know up-front if a group is the last group.

As a bonus, not using the `:last-of-type`/`:last-child` selector nets you better IE8 compatibility, if you care about that.