# CSS Selector: Last-child not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the following example the first-child selector works, the last-child doesn't. Please see attached screenshots.

The Problem: My class "gotit" colors the bar green, the class "go4" colors it grey. The last gotit should be red. Sounds simple, huh?

So now dig in: If I try to select the first-child, it works like a charm:
[image]

If I try to select the last-child, it just does nothing.
[image]

Anyone here with a hint whats wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give us some code to work with, and a demo on https://jsfiddle.net :-)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a paragraph inside a span.

Comment: you want the last element with class `.gotit` not the last-child

Comment: thanks @Quentin - its just prototyping, but you're wright and I am thankful for your hint! I will correct it right now.

Comment: Please proved all your relevant markup in the post, not just a screenshot. Currently we cannot be sure of what the last child of `.progress` is. I'm guessing there is something else going on that hasn't been shared yet (extra markup, extra CSS). A very basic working example of what you have is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rq0gwno5/), `.gotit` has to be the last child of `.parent` to work. If it isn't, [this will happen](https://jsfiddle.net/rq0gwno5/1/).

Comment: Almost certain duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: @DaniP sounds like its an understanding. Could you provide me some example code or link to get further information? Right now i cant move on with this snippet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements here you can begin or the duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `.gotit` is actually the last child of `.parent`. Like below.

```css
.inner {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
.inner:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If it isn't, using `:last-child` with `.gotit` won't work. See below.

```css
.inner,
.inner-other {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
.inner:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner-other"></div>
  <div class="inner-other"></div>
  <div class="inner-other"></div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing your markup looks like the above markup. Try regrouping your elements to help ensure that [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) or [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) will work. Something like below.

```css
.inner div,
.inner-other div {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
.inner div:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-other">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```