# how to change font color of last element with specific class

Tags: css

here is my html

```css
.user-container div.user-left:last-child{
  color:red;
}
.user-container div.user-right:last-child{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-container">
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text. this is user left last</div>
    <div class="user user-right">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-right">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-right">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-right">Some text. this is user right last</div>
</div>
```

is there any way to change font color of last child of class 'user-left' and class 'user-right' using CSS ? in here user-right:last-child working but user-left:last-child not working.any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You should enclose user-left into specific container `left` and user-right to `right`

Because last-child selector works only in parent container :)

```css
.left div:last-child {
  color:red;
}
.right div:last-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-left">Some text. this is user left last</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="user user-right">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-right">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-right">Some text.</div>
    <div class="user user-right">Some text. this is user right last</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the last child, because the user-right divs are also children of the same parent. The selector you would want is :last-of-type but that only works on elements, not by class. I don't think you can do it in pure CSS without changing the html structure. The other answer -- using nth-last-child -- will only work for your example. It breaks as soon as you add or remove any elements.

You can find more information here: [CSS: How to say .class:last-of-type [classes, not elements!]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   .user-container div.user-left:nth-last-child(5) {
    background: red;
   }
```

Comment: working.but what if i don't know number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:last-of-type` pseudo selector of css

`.user-left:last-of-type,
.user-right:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}`

Comment: The last-of-type not working for classname.
From http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:last-of-type
The :last-of-type pseudo-class represents an element that is the last sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.
Because it has to be a sibling, it ignores classnames probably because then you can mix it up with other elements.

Comment: @사드루완 I update my answer, just add the `.user-left` class, sorry i fotgot to include that class.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS OUT:
HTML PART:

```
<div class="user-container">
<ul>
<li>Some text.</li>
<li>Some text.</li>
<li>Some text.</li>
<li">Some text.</li>
<li class="lastLeft">Some text. this is user left last</li>
<li>Some text.</li>
<li>Some text.</li>
<li>Some text.</li>
<li class="lastRight">Some text. this is user right last</li></ul>
</div>
```

CSS PART:

```
.user-container ul li.lastRight {
color:red;
}
.user-container ul li.lastLeft {
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) selector, [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```css
.user-container > div.user-left:not(:has(~.user-left)) {
  color: red;
}

.user-container > div.user-right:not(:has(~.user-right)) {
  color: red;
}
```