# Last element inside a link, inside a class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to call out the last element inside a link, inside a class. But the challenges is I can not just use the "last-of-type" or the "last child" of card_content, because there is a version of .card that is not a link.

```css
a.card:link .card_content:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ff6600;
}


.card{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0.5px solid #efefef;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="card" >
<div class="card_icon">image go here</div>
<div class="card_content">
<h3>I am a header</h3>
<p>I am some description.</p>
<p>Need this to be 0 on margin-bottom</p>
</div>
<div class="card_line">
Click</div>
</a>

<div class="card" >
<div class="card_content">
<p>none link version</p>
<p>Need this to be 0 on margin-bottom</p>
</div>
<div class="card_line">
Click</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `last-of-type` does not work on classes, this is the closest you can get via pure `CSS`. This solution presupposes that the last instance of `.card_content` is the second element from the end.

```css
a.card[href] .card_content:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

.card {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0.5px solid #efefef;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="card">
  <div class="card_icon">image go here</div>
  <div class="card_content">
    <h3>I am a header</h3>
    <p>I am some description.</p>
    <p>Need this to be 0 on margin-bottom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card_content">
    <h3>I am a header</h3>
    <p>I am some description.</p>
    <p>Need this to be 0 on margin-bottom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card_line">
    Click</div>
</a>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card_content">
    <p>none link version</p>
    <p>Need this to be 0 on margin-bottom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card_line">
    Click</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:last-of-type` will work on an element, but not on a class.

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) says:

> The :last-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the last element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements) also discusses this.