# CSS get last child of a class

Tags: css

Is there any way to select the last class inside a parent ?

There is a fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/98oc4Ler/

I tried both :

```
#banner-message .test:last-of-type {
  background: red;
}
#banner-message .test:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

But it doesn't work, is there any way to select last element with a class inside a parent ?

Comment: No, but you might be able to apply styles to `.test` and revert  them in `.test ~ .test`. (That’s a *compatible* idea, not necessarily a good one, too.)

Comment: So there is not "simple" selector" for what I want ?

Comment: No, there isn’t.

Comment: @Ry- OK thanks, this is what I wanted to know, I'll use your way

Comment: Unfortunately finding the last `.class` is not possible with `last-of-type`.
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453/css-how-to-say-classlast-of-type-classes-not-elements)