# Why is only 1 out of 2 last-of-type CSS working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have multiple div container "footer-ad-button". Some of these are in a div container called "platinum" others in "gold". The following CSS code behaves pretty weird to me. If i have both ads active, platinum and gold, the "margin-bottom: 0" works only for the last gold ad, but not for the last platinum ad. If i deactivate all gold ads, it works for the last platinum ad.

Conclusion: Somehow this code works only for one of both last-of-type css rules (depends on which html is active), but i don't see any reason why it behaves like this.

CSS:

```
.ad .footer-ad-button{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.ad > div > .platinum:last-of-type > .footer-ad-button,
.ad > div > .gold:last-of-type > .footer-ad-button{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ad"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="platinum">
                    <div aria-label="Advertisement" class="footer-ad-button" onclick="location.href = '/'">
                        <div class="advertise-inner"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="platinum">
                    <div aria-label="Advertisement" class="footer-ad-button" onclick="location.href = '/'">
                        <div class="advertise-inner"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>  
                    
                    <div class="gold">
                    <div aria-label="Advertisement" class="footer-ad-button" onclick="location.href = '/'">
                        <div class="advertise-inner"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="gold">
                    <div aria-label="Advertisement" class="footer-ad-button" onclick="location.href = '/'">
                        <div class="advertise-inner"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't have HTML elements in a button. If you do they will behave weirdly. Probably not the problem here - just for your info.

Comment: Well, not all of them anyway. You can have non-interactive phrasing elements in a button.

Comment: It's not the button, there is no change in behaviour if i change it to a div.

Comment: The closest duplicates of this question kinda suck ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211453) one's halfway decent, but it's closed a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268), whose answers are either wrong or completely missing the point), so I'm just going to point you to the absolute most general question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector In short, the "type" refers to the tag name, which in this case is div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last-of-type` selects the last element with that type (not class, not id), so while you are expecting `.platinum:last-of-type` to select the last element with class `platinum` (which is not necessarily the last element of that type), it is selecting the element which has the `platinum` class AND is the last child element with that type in its parent. In your case, that type is a `<div>`, but it could've as well been a `<section>` or something else.

Currently the CSS specification does not define such a selector that does what you are aiming for, so you will need to introduce some javascript to dynamically select the elements you want.

Comment: "is the last child element of its parent" would be :last-child. This is :last-of-type, which matches the last div (and would still match the last div.gold, if its following sibling was something other than a div).

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: I get the point. In that case i could do a workaround with a div for one class (gold) and a span for the other class (platinum). With that i have 2 elements that i can use a last-of-type on, instead of using javascript.

Comment: This is also possible, yes.