# last-child selecting wrong div

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting `:last-child` to work in my situation.

HTML:

```
<div class="test">Some content</div>
<div class="test">Some content</div>
<div class="test">Some content</div>
<div class="action">Some other content</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.topic {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

div.topic:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97Dr4/)

The last `div.test` still has the border at the bottom.
​
The problem I think is that the `border-bottom: none` applies to the very last div which is `div.action` and not to the last div of class test.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css your question is,possibly, a duplicate. Short answer there's no `:last-of-class` selector, so you'd need to use JavaScript or use [`border-top`](http://jsfiddle.net/97Dr4/1/).

Comment: The solution to the question you linked to is using absolute orderding (ie. 4th item) while my divs are generated by the server and I don't know how many there are.

Comment: oops, I copied from the wrong tab XD I've edited the original comment, and changed to the link I meant to copy. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update your markup in order to achieve desired result. Wrap your unknown items in a wrapper, eg:

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/97Dr4/2/)

```
<div id="list">
 <div class="topic">Some content</div>
 <div class="topic">Some content</div>
 <div class="topic">Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="action">Some other content</div>​
```

then use this CSS:

```
#list .topic {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#list .topic:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: I think I will have to go with this one. I am just surprised that this selector works this way (ie. ignores the class...).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `first-child`, not `last-child`.

```
div.topic {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

div.topic:first-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

This works with your current HTML, and is more cross-browser compatible.

Comment: more cross-browser compatible than what? `:first-child` is as well supported as `:last-child`. Both don't work in older browsers and IE.

Comment: @Horen first-child works in IE8, but last-child does not. http://jsfiddle.net/JT5SN/3/. (see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)