# Namespacing pseudo-selector by css class

Tags: css

So I tried googling this but find it quite difficult to get the right search terms in.

I'm trying to namespace a pseudo-selector on only a certain class

In this example, without the class the last `Hi` should be blue. I would expect this code to turn the second `span` blue, which is not the case. Am I doing something wrong or do I have an unreasonable expectation of what CSS should be doing?

```css
span.dinosaur:last-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span class='dinosaur'>Hi</span>
  <span class='dinosaur'>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would expect this code to turn the second `span` blue, which is not the case.

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the `:last-child` pseudo-class; it matches only if the element to which the pseudo-class is applied, only if that element is the last-child of its parent. It is *not* equivalent to `:last-of-type()` selector (and even *that* pseudo-class disregards class-names and `id`, and selects an element based on its element-type (`<div>`, `<p>` etc).

In future, `:nth-match()` might serve your purpose, but that's yet to be implemented (so far as I'm aware) in any browser, and is part of the Selectors Level 4 module.

References:

- [`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo).
- [`:last-of-type()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo).
- [`:nth-match()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#nth-match-pseudo).
- [`:nth-last-match()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#nth-last-match-pseudo).
- [Selectors Level 4 module](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/).

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable enough, and kind of the answer I expected. So if I wanted to do what I'm trying to do, what would the best way to approach it be?

Comment: @StefanDorunga To expand on what David said, think of `span.dinosaur:last-child` as first selecting the last child span, and then only matching if that span has the dinosaur class. It won't do what I think you're thinking it will do, and select the last child span that has the dinosaur class. It's a common misconception.

Comment: So for now, without javascript I have no solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not; unfortunately.