# Target last instance of class in parent

Tags: html, css

I have said divs:

```
<div>
    <div class="p1"></div>
    <div class="p2"></div>
    <div class="p1"></div>
    <div class="p2"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="p1"></div>
    <div class="p2"></div>
    <div class="p1"></div>
    <div class="p2"></div>
</div>
```

I want to style the last p1 div in each parent div. I've tried some last-child code, but it doesn't want to take. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no selector that can target the last instance of a class in css, currently, if you can use jquery, this would be a fairly easy task

Comment: No way to do this in CSS. You'll need to write a bit of JS to find all the children with class `p1`, then apply styling to the last of them.

Comment: @OP please clarify if you can use javascript/jquery for an answer or not and also clarify if your code structure is always like this or is this just a simplified example.

Comment: If you want to do it in pure CSS - you will have to add a second class to the last element. A la http://stackoverflow.com/a/6401298/961695

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't be done with pure css. I reccomend this using jquery:

```js
$("div").find(".p1:last").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="p1">not</div>
  <div class="p2">not</div>
  <div class="p1">this</div>
  <div class="p2">not</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="p1">not</div>
  <div class="p2">not</div>
  <div class="p1">this</div>
  <div class="p2">not</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good and simple solution +1

Comment: @FahadHasan true if OP wanted a jquery solution, I assume not since there is no javascript or jquery tag

Answer (score 0):

You can't target the last element with class for `p1` ... But if your structure is like that always and right after `p1`  is `p2` . Then you know that the last `p1` will be the penultimate element, you can try this:

```
.p1:nth-last-child(2) {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Here some info about [:nth-last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child).

And **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzhued3h/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This function finds the last child of some element with a given class:

```
function last_of_class(elt, cls) {
    var children = elt.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    return children[children.length-1];
}
```

Now, you can use this to apply a class or some styling:

```
var last_p1 = last_of_class(parent, 'p1');
last_p1.classList.add('last-p1');

.last-p1 { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS supports the `:last-of-type` selector. However, that will *not* select the *last* occurence of a class, but the last occurence of a TYPE.

So, as a *hack*, you could define your own types instead of classes and use that selector:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p1>1</p1>
    <p1>2</p1>
    <p2>3</p2>
</div>
<div>
    <p1>1</p1>
    <p1>2</p1>
    <p2>3</p2>
    <p1>4</p1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p1{
    display:block;
}
p2{
    display:block;
}

div p2:last-of-type{
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwa8y85n/2/

for older browser, you would need to teach them about the element(s) using some javascript, like

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script> document.createElement("p1"); document.createElement("p2"); </script>
<![endif]-->
```

but then you could pretty much use the jquery way... consider this answer as an "option" :-)

Comment: If the OP can change the code that much then why not add a class to the last p1 instead

Comment: He didn't mention that he cannot change the code. Maybe he just uses a foreach to generate the entries, and does not know, when hitting the last element of a certain type to add the proper "class"?

Comment: @dognose: Very creative, but I mean gosh, the `<p1>` element is not going to act like a `<p>` at all, so is this really a good direction to go in, aside from the valid point raised by @Huangism?

Comment: @dognose I don't know, only the OP can answer that

Comment: @torazaburo well, you can add *any* style information to pX to act like a `<p>` - that's no problem.

Comment: But after all the jQuery way is the better way I'd say. The **best** way would be the suggestion from Huan, to generate the element in question with  `class="p2 last"` when building the html-markup.