# Select Last Nested Element

Tags: html, css, selector, children

How do I select the last `has-errors` div below?

```
<section class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          stuff
    </div>
</section>
```

I can select the first `has-errors` using:

```
.form-block .form-group.has-errors:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But `last-child` does not work above. How do I select the last instance of `.form-group.has-errors`?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqrjh6ev/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select the "last child" with a specific class name in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css)

Comment: The solution is much different in the question linked above. The solution in the linked answer in inapplicable to my use case. The answer below is a method applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS it will be tough unless there are some specific rules - like it's always the 2nd from last. In short what you're asking for is like `last-of-class`, which doesn't exist. There is `last-of-type` but that only applies to element type (`div`, `p`, etc), not to classes.

The next best option is some vanilla JS to grab the last element with the `.form-group.has-error` class.

```js
const hasErrors = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group.has-errors');
hasErrors[hasErrors.length -1].style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<section class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          stuff
    </div>
</section>
```

To make this useful for multiple form blocks on a page it could be modified to:

```js
const formGroups = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.form-block'));


formGroups.forEach(function(block) {
  const hasErrors = block.querySelectorAll('.form-group.has-errors');
  hasErrors[hasErrors.length -1].style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
Form Block 1
<section class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          stuff
    </div>
</section>

Form Block 2
<section class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-errors">
          ERROR!
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          stuff
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Use `for()` instead of `forEach()`. It's [`a lot faster`](https://jsperf.com/ktest23) and works in IE11.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I can't see nesting in your code.

Nested elements should be disposed like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    stuff
    <div class="form-group">
        stuff
        <div class="form-group">
              stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

no answer to my problem here.
maybe the title not to be exact