# Last type of class

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to select the last of every class type. I don't know how many list items are present, so I can't use `nth-child(2)` for example. Can I make this in css or do I have to add a `last` class width scripts?

- group-1
- group-1
- group-2
- group-2
- group-3
- group-3

```css
.group-1:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.group-2:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.group-3:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="group-1">Group1</li>
  <li class="group-1">Group1</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-3">Group3</li>
  <li class="group-3">Group3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add another class to those `li` that you want to select or you can use the pseudo-selector `:last-child`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **adjacent sibling combinator** `+` css selector.

`element1 + element2` means it will select the second element `element2` only if it immediately follows the first element `element1`.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.group-1+.group-2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.group-2+.group-3 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="group-1">Group1</li>
  <li class="group-1">Group1</li>
  <li class="group-1">Group1</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-2">Group2</li>
  <li class="group-3">Group3</li>
  <li class="group-3">Group3</li>
  <li class="group-3">Group3</li>
  <li class="group-3">Group3</li>
  <li class="group-3">Group3</li>
</ul>
```

> **Reference Link [`adjacent sibling combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**

Comment: Good trick when we have to deal with margin, but it become more tricky if we have to set a color to last one for example :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah you are right. If want to change styling to last element we can use jQeury `last()` method.

Comment: yes sure, with jQuery is easy ;) but we always have this philosophic non-ending question : "how to do it with pure CSS ?" :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use: **:nth-child(2n)** in css

```
li:nth-child(2n){
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: "I don't know how many list items that are comming, so I can't use nth-child(2) for example."

Comment: So please see this link 
[Last Item in class css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css) it will help you