# CSS - Select last child which was visible using special class

Tags: css

I'm trying to add some CSS on the last visible list item using pure CSS.
Technically, I wanted to set `margin-right` to zero (0) on the last visible item. Before mark as duplicate, please understand the case.

The background story is all items are loaded during page load and `enabled` class was added after doing some Ajax response.

```css
.ring-navigations__menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.ring-navigations__menu___item{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #d7c5c5;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.ring-navigations__menu___item.enabled{
    display: block;
}
.ring-navigations__menu___item.enabled:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ring-navigations__menu">
    <li class="ring-navigations__menu___item enabled">List Items</li>
    <li class="ring-navigations__menu___item">List Items</li>
    <li class="ring-navigations__menu___item enabled">List Items</li>
    <li class="ring-navigations__menu___item">List Items</li>
</ul>
```

Looking to handle those through Pure CSS (No JavaScript).
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking to a pure CSS solution, please remove the `javascript` tag

Comment: I believe you should refer this, it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css#answer-37588181) may help.

Comment: @Pritesh `:last-of-type` won't help here. As it says it applies to elements which are the last of a given type in this case `li`. If the targeted `li` isn't the last one in the list `:last-of-type` will not work.

Comment: @OlivierKrull You are right, I got it, Thanks mate :)

Comment: @OlivierKrull can you please also make jsfiddle or something would be of great help to achieve the same in this case?

Comment: @Pritesh Would be something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8htvpdm0/). But as the answer in my link says, the order of the DOM elements must be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a class to a parent tag when your Ajax response is triggered like so :

```
.loaded .ring-navigations__menu___item.enabled{
    display: block;
}
.loaded .ring-navigations__menu___item.enabled:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```