# Not selector does not behave like it should

Tags: css, sass

This is my HTML Code

```
<div class="col-1-of-2">
            <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">
              You're going to fall in love with nature
            </h3>
            <p class="paragraph">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">
              Live adventure like you never have before
            </h3>
            <p class="paragraph">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn-text">Learn More &rarr;</a>
          </div>
```

Now here I'm applying CSS styling on paragraph class like this

```
.paragraph{
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  &:not(:last-child)
  {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }
}
```

But It still apply margin bottom to the last paragraph have a look here

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong, Please guide me in right direction
Thanks

Comment: But your last-child is `<a class="btn-text">` so it applies css correctly

Comment: Can you clear my doubt Please I'm apply this on .paragraph class, So Doesn't it select only paragraph last-child?

Comment: Can you guide me how Can I apply to last paragraph only?

Comment: Okay Got it! I've to use last-of-type. Thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target the last instance of the class name in your list without JS. You can only target the last tag

```
p:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

Read [How do I select the "last child" with a specific class name in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css)